# Send the pairs in smallest output

Tags: code-challenge, compression

Write two programs A and B.

- Program A (the encoder) takes 1024 pairs of integers \$(k,v)\$, where \$0≤k<2^{32}\$ and \$0≤v<1024\$, and all \$k\$ will be different. It will output a single positive integer (likely a few thousand digits long).
- Program B (the decoder) takes two inputs: the output-integer of program A, and one \$k\$ from the input pairs we've used as input for program A. It will output the \$v\$ corresponding with the given \$k\$.

In other words, Program A compresses 1024 key-value pairs to the smallest size possible, and Program B must use the data provided by A to recover each value given its corresponding key.

Your score is the average value of the output of program A for the test data. Hardcoding for a given test case is forbidden, so this should be essentially the same as the score on the pretest data. Pretest data and test data are drawn from the same (uniform) distribution.

Random pretest data is available [here](https://tio.run/##XY9BT4QwEIXv/IrJmk2oLAroaZeu2WSvcvBkwhJTacEBLKSUk@GviwWyKPYw6bx535tM2jRunqbDcIMyrTouIGw1x/ru42itpArf/2lCm5aLDKWACHwveLQ62WIuBQeUGnKhFZPcHv9I4AuU0J2SgE/LxPXJbeAoyXmubbL3DtBbo/2TobQNYoF5q1AWR8lhkrNawZxNDYdhZIrjjJAS@9Ew@Ut6XfYQkBlcwcUIFyGaYuBlPuEZ2CwuEkpLAnmta3PAb0KjDG4cm20H2@4iNzsod8vNvkf@bGMxJrSc@97qh@E7zSqWt4N7vt5O7Ykjx5dTdH57Pr3eB@QH).

```
Random.txt
MD5: 6FA62A283282F5CFBC6E089B2369C9B9
SHA1: 0BF7FB62A8566575D4A948DD34A559BAAAC422FC
CRC32: 2675DAB3

Testdata.txt
MD5: 6C8F90F126C8F3C55A9FC9F22733CE55
SHA1: F7D11AAB54393DE8CC4E75565950D8C6D9CFE42A
CRC32: B3DB1479
```

Actual test cases:

https://www.mediafire.com/folder/i6hmn9zzk73ig/174035

A stupid program A that work but totally didn't optimize is [here](https://tio.run/##PZvZjgXZUUXf8yvy0Q0InXlA4ksQD7bEYAnZLWMk8/VmrZ1lsLC7um5lnhPDjh074v76v3/@zz/@of/1r395//ktz7//8U/v79/f/@H902//8B//9pta2vjln573/Zff/sPv/pVP/P4Pv/7Pn3/zyz/@96//9Xv@l9/4d395/@4d/Z4y1qy1lvH@PZ/8829@@wu/8Bk/P//ul@fXP/EP72/@8stf/9pruXOUWva7235qL/XUscZ9z@5Pm2OP1c8o7zz8uFsf99693jEPP56zSj@7vvfy42ljl9V7eevazz2HP7xlvW3Mh4PxmXLGeWsbT138cV9l7XfN9vTRax9l1vXefZ7Fqcqou7x3Pu2O1VYp9b5rl6dxt9P2bf09tzyj8MrSy@S3fT979t0an3nPmvxyrtU4w3hnPw82qWus0t41eOfsc93BjV8u9fQ@B3bg0e@o9emrj1PrbBO73KeeUy8Pe@e8z2h7jI2l5ts6f8ll1up337eeZ67aytn7vFzv4ep1jHX65trl6VhwtsP1Xgzj1eYe94z99rY4URllaPL3PN1n8NQ@3r04be0VizWvPYZ/yf@tvdtbR334VR1944AXw@A2/nK2zr15PD@WceZs3gWj1N768gMvn@z1ruXd3jrx0pyl7VkPTqvFM1ysXW/D3zymYbzJjd6@NwarOOwMbLJyglYwDK9snO@U2g926S@xiMFw5i6ba9f@fL9Ypb4L4y1CD6N2PM8nW1ljY8nVCSkeM25btzYsS7zVMwkvvMlf9vJUzjrPKb2@eFzbntH5e@51sPzE8kSRLuNia9exFw7Oj@fOu2458z0JeiKjkTXE0OFihPg5nJgcwL04lz/RR3URQiQHHyfAJjGEK88lVrlnrRj61r5wZz/vLDxoldM6lynclN/yVsKY/3mJkWeM44ebv1xenCOVjVfaJBROaXeXur1qfw5OWNiUoGrYYfN0YmEZf@RdPTy2cGyM3R980jlkwQ866bZ25yFUuT9G6WvgjcZzDFxycnO@8@6OASvRiNsmMcWJ6iJX@D0fPgRn3QODE/jru2o7hZDCXoTYIL1vu9yAsL916KkzGlYkD3HjBmMwGQZdxtEmbCsQsfgR65PB/GfiKP6STD@Ly1XfOh9wjNfw9PtuHlTbaiQfEfueyu2KL@r@LX/ykPr3kNWH/Jnjmb3chqFILs7beQd5CML4IICtFTLCQN9kl8afZ4MiJO@zFxFKsK7NK3kn1p@XwBYCx@ZfnHPwmtjEy8nZdrD2eTgMMEW0vGAHfgExMH95CWljY5LCwCDZQ0AKAsQ@f9nNEFLp4tHbCd7x3E5U44u3C7OYR3C8ix/rQzLzEyAfb9dF3E9cvEHO@pCfdZrgXIukJKaXCW3akf6dFDwASitFGKg4nP8nt4jkZukAf0i1gimJPuBl6c/hETh75QXY/RCAeLtwfwAFZz378g78yYkII8PPUOWAd@ttcAPz8VHweeIgbLbaS/Tiv5bEA4LX3BhhkdAAGD6yRoDZZAQZAOZejIn1SNFbpmhz8RCJQ7h5l8FTMdfmrDx0EJgjVUkME7MOvgPXDVQsT2INS6JGAElqwgAQw/TkxuVaNfm6DrmFCQR9isWiHnAg/lJs5MSjHIsfMPOkIvHWnmjrJiFXAWDu1EmgFO7kRODLbYeYtxK2IBNQTDFJSHN6aiqVh/jaArlxQFLVTaZP3QBgFw7lGeIHQIRCQWRcXoOVMWcVB8grCiPRNzkDhgcFisneLLgc93q4IeThd//ytoqjNofgTM0fxhXzSAHMx2/B1W328mcAMv6c4hTwQZY3EofqQMiTfg2TjZ/cAbsLcdUAGPHQ0MQpxIIIPYYBCcK/JDTGbyTPMupBdasNxwE0eko5VZx0xooknifcmAz4B6pAQJCriV7gS6FWky2EsjBL4eREizRck7DnMeA1@ECwEpz4BY@ebWyYEnE/HiKQMakcRXSvJNMV8SiTqcg7XIg3Ul8v@PqCCBQNArTJGSgTBAAQAjhAfnAUnsFlBF6x5lpw9jbzPP46FnOMJpoS3MMaw2c9cgXVCikz1wArOL8XBx4pEJwNHMOtZNDEyIAcQCDIDBAeWgHupmL3jjOJrWlskZYELdBqxeaslFMOdj5UHpLGuXWs1IQ/PBwMQAImH4sYuVswFDRGzONQnGGJ0RSBWXgNnhmkFI/Vc5MffU7B9pRm46WK2HOBF1i8Gy8EKPxlDpwMAJialFBB0UL7bDnPCOeZgn8XOghfcJDXEi6ckaN8iEXVpjJzSNJeLsVrzXtyjmSg6AJhOM8n63jMgDdI3hBDogMatMIzempx1R3QHmkZXoDgQW@5PI/qYxZYdhXXOTNJzN0pvlSaB5aDlS48DGSAvvDvhpgqmSFxzcJBtWrmnFizu2mFWaCwUOrwVj4J@SA2SWW8Oh94k7EO8nCdRxI2ANWVom0IA3XXvywUB06yJZFck1fAKAlhYhPjy5@u7HyEVJAZxAqpSt1LKFGRiXCgh1QGN@kLCEmOIcngw@MK3BB@MpvA4p/upS7@f8ZhvkEUjpRPbQ8yvITIA7wTWtCD0DKYfpfBBxIgNiKf9f8VxkV76DL80p8a9BbrgpNLMsW9K3BWRJppvaJsFDCNWjssCOYmUYtTmhZbIA5gTMiaqsa2v6QbwJ/zNkrQlQU1uYoYS05zIv4UVgYmw8E56SNTGQeaRjALk1yTXxPqGIJ6BYGTyBb@kpwnyDbVbKd1IrtJoGEC8VGBYUn1T2BzkHZkJH4Ffk1boBk@BRLydLEO3OOoK9FAVlA8jiajk@DmsEQCeXhzzMuRwB7PACqJBZd6VD6CJz/BEnrYm3bicco8XjkPLqUB493JTIgELI1S0z/2B@8j/2nYSDbObztmKt@PAMChKCWbukQ@e/5NKbTfODI6nD8I8yZlno8G0vzUMDkbVRUmbjTbCxAoVxpKnRSDoJcEJTcj34mMZXMESgL8j3lVQ/2wE5WGQrQ8nkV9pTyIp9QfIo6T02ta6uh3lt0QsJhWBAa@O04kxjEBkS1wk64pKiAXnzaXSEWq6/DPlmFjySyQkiqxeOFZUCPYspWM1AGqrekrDaDG6PgghUtOwW8LiEIeXfHbHmbYfQGuxH/ChDJWJBFE2pLXf12dkMz7gFZSZxu3JDSx1dITwJRJZrCd5nakXwRNjsWqSAWWVcUGLLkNk8F6zdbNJ3XZANAAKBMmACnET8btAckL4lrssX@o0kTsTMhcIwjH97QT166YXxL0xB9AOZIAdNRYBKpMCEHR6GBsaXY6BtsZfM/xgRBdKe04cnfuuiULUAsYXUsDAZLzLzB2lXSQMLyq37SefJRnU0tguSEdBKJZgFMNmytJH3YBxy6RIC9y2RwKvG1mTDNwqFb0DgNb8NaBSbkPaMmRoYNqC1RXi1ULiwNPKNPySKkNRbrUZVhRbkloUof4JwRIXrvavoO2eMP@F79QEMDSbhMJ/B1BkGJULQti07TaYAfiT54tkCUiKFJUJ6r/SM2GowBulMBqY9@5O4ckYK/VfwXIfA0oxYeJDlBborks4XZaVSXC5FIj4tBExLH9sAxT@0fi2Ysfwjm8wd4Ahkr8SFfgJ11@DxOjSiu5VN8xrTRgDn961YEoieDneULiCG2QzF6gKrqQRpJkW3RimwMttRv5vrFyxQm7t0ujCujzVN8JRpMchC@ZiPtJL8rV/Uog76RYGM1GkmgP7EF803HQhWFramJC1FcCHPRIuJTHkl0WOdsB6DZPI1SOYoguhtcdCw6Hp@fYBqFNOdGMn6gQHbDGQiYUmUZAAG3pyEl/AVO/mCVAHyUuTeLWuBYjGMxJXyhdIxyt33RsNNFcR2z5JI4rD6PwEg1gNCUVa96wyvKxbSBiUhioiNQ/kJ1/Q1ngsZRen0TbWg0cMgv/kglpyiAv4CqXV1yiHGGP5c1BzGNluCpGXRyssQMfhooROWQQHEiKhj@I7f1hP22c3bzsaNA@WeNJNxqsSoABqfAe7GTUcUlSe5l9vgj0glgQkwaLLBFv7Y@jdRlHgd/xEycGbK17ALfyF5znxMQEs502VXeXAUXWohSRYnvWoi9gPoKKiDZaJKRNai2Nb@p8CmEEJYjGFWyTaCOwKLchlDwNULIs6UcVRvgwAuzgsRmAa48Hjxm2NsY1SYvx6JeISYyrYOnjACEskrOOHNZKKtWj56Gzxe/pQKGeAnOxItgKDImhnUMIR9cvdua8Zxu9eAlAomRHSIEVwNqiA9GwVsoB5U2BKRVBbJA4AnXLIy5Frh45rAmfEmhiZYmY0jKF0aVJTje2ud1rIvJPIJdS3jD5L1fluthETbWR0JQ1IDc4cpbReqFAJTFGWbHJ6VZJ0nT3T5ADIeEzqsl6pW4Rh/A1LOQeBN2WtUpMIZs6u9qkWWV8kHoD/rXdU@SAuIMxP3VDI@DX9GyS2HPUbmeYEwYWTFfw0epPZKrP2BPw1n5VI@g50neJ51RG6FOYFXamIwCx@k96Kc2WvKckbY8NNSdWzgbMbU7VsHgrdIdqK6ArX1uqaKeGDMCGH5eMT7/pUY/5u4X3hw09B@buS5ZI/a8kBziy70097XZd9N58WDGeok3WYnuytB2sL7eQkk/rxg6TrVJe0UD2pIa4UoGwj07k8LR1Kojqwar6PLZLYfvCFmnwtRGv4fRtpOBThClC0KljasHgJVj@qMkIsBT4HuN3mc/AgHBkAQn0gSOHQgFVwr9lTl2y8HC86hACXOCeV9FhpBVV9AVVlcmj3RZJOACLTbpVY0cZuulLVLZpdWtLKbAW6cT5Uc9jdwOd52I3lgflwILz@cVWn2TkE2TP@GQEyTPA0MuHOKSE0ct7aPH3WCH36yrSwAGaSv0uaXF5KoHIkeB/FiS5s5MOHsVzN4W0SnL4oF6QuFz7W2oKRUdVOjSaTINmqympRpGjRPPMCYrHjQ/pYtJfUIr8dFFxHdbzSdJdFbIWROTjDcTkSD1THV41jZXrLIHL5BSivf23jaJpALbRE5D75DRmwqU0GriD0J6WT4oRh4RM5kcIFd63/GvRpIzlqUd6m8EyGkpbq2b5ombAq8KM@zfQKLZWJVIRECgkOaWySeMU3JYOizYH0xzJzI3i4IPh5VAv2NVR5uS1gBegDoLmUIuySSDSY2KJFSHDtqb7YcKHO8zMENK0bRrbrrSuSpDayzmdaO2olUMW6u3bQ7w6X6JeZax2HWscm9ehWg4jsmhqcdsnM9GGVilWQRyywCc4heKEg5xGU6J2pExGcT6Wt/MT09XRy9Cstm1DmOdVOF5VyhkC4b2U2Eh0YRysNHlFDLktR4ROSPw7F4QNFRnt/QmwlM0rXQccr1pDC25V8ob37Klz1cbUVqSwJzwUkOXNtDwn8CKud2UHKXdXJed@ewdYHaHwqSa@jAf6AaY2e/5jX9xsRCL@R7SB/JPqlh4FCkifsw3Ig9O85oyBD3zR5pBJ8rE/HoWFSIH@CUuO8@jXcK58zfEZ8Fz4rLOYqYI8nV5RRD@ZFZM6YGlNMdzUAxcI@a3eTCsId4A5Xwd@ikU2Lcvs8chkPnFqtzetTg5blwQV30n2IOFmJXzTfnM7TxMq4g@VfYvm/UaxgxI3bDOoR7YqzlTw3dkhoEM@Tnnl@pcOI5ySZqV@guK2Bi/HUE3ewiuKwzHsFqUfw51El0gBz@Ap9HtyJXBbocIKecNyl4o5sAwLko3AccgH@2yO31PRwdBXxXsfEZ1sEB@B6wuXUthX5lNWOPLwYIqKu2aAkzvoXErPZOLNILGJeJD5YufqyI8z8AqCRS5POYfOcRwM1B1tQcGVv7dil7PTe8WIazvhJIgkpfTb2YEWUI7Zo0LhcBkjXUVoVlMgqg5BScUK7aNn2FFY1HWgizDEvb7JSFdshkAK2nAQm6P1xU86NOihyTh/Rte0AXvbivJE@zPn45GaViSWbXNy1MKEWufl06eB0maRAldKzjevcTxRU6VDp4ZoU8oMefFCTUHkG1Bv@3aqpdDkEHrKpMkmik4RiD/ZbX6JvkiVsh2JhMqAEAqFsnAFJRitkw3Hs9ygk7iydqJOv/JZMnbYiFkk6SGhAEoSIyN0xd/6qaFqL8RtgfpwARUkbKMrVcAsJYqaMACiuwmBGGQ5Ag@No/biaz4BaE/h0k7boWYmp5KFFglU9bFmnp6BD/CrnqcexOU8Ep8H1YpGrMkMGQsu8LIeX3EjElPEmZ05krhFNj3blIMD2ZmppVLEHcGu@NLefk9onWJ0pNWjZvczaFXvysCM0pcfh0LTiK7THtLR@pbGbDnsU40BVx30Xlti1wNkPsuK2pwNWUQAQOAOpk88CA@2qs743pM/3E35nCQX7txeECGcPdookJnnm2xFfeRiaknjE@GrhGBK3SEPMkkHWcp3PElp/JNhsb1681qZIKir2nvUzLxppbpsW5WSZ@PDmy6dAN42hoqRc1nHakYgPncQn1x75KPUAOn1/oYpEqbhQAIUXUrIwu0yi8xH3Nt9caOECx@qD1aKzFLwNvEgWWwSVFUEgKk76NdppddMdL9dDbjANZENXzWz7rAQNwLHVrG1KKx49wt9PDcl/CX6s8NyawYxOHgrJgsJzPxWosABiT96pOaYvSZNwJ4RdOahS6AqTyZyzcnPEFJ5XpYfSNHHac1WWTgRhfGfwALmfiVL2FQNJJ@4rUO7aZ44nZL1QGxcTYDI3G/edByWU66tLMAxTMy5uUIrhk8L3GqGyFTfXIe7YCNKKqFCoLfPRs43BCEnTOlWgSg5jw2UJIwnqxWS8OrhtsTXPpbyRIWYbgscJ8aORqqaIxXM/HaYs3TavVkBIKPd6RHJuUraSshE8U9tbImIqJUwGiLTAXnkBQxGCvja9OUOAe@nKUaLAMoW1MgP2z0PZZiedYfAyBJwrYs1q07Qo5nmYUudKGfDVrt@1GnTvHAbh7g1hXHaSCYXvQ91ihyTuWtuGy/HKTVs4ngb@7hI0JjrghscOh0V3srO1HTeuzQFjBQQu9mpMtslTIa@ZOPYNUXqmqZtzU6JiTAj4mx3OfSAsgMnvLRZtHVKXe4hLAq2w2KHZ1F8XekJ6e9Wi3UT6zJQIJ2ysp3/ZbMCKg6g7Jopl42Ts4qxv2JKBvBpOQXVdGeomgbSLSL1IcUal0foU40nD3JEFHmZFga6nQgJ7URcUx8h@MJyuIHUoH/iGAZy90UgqM4@qC10HyuSnIoXSH8ctf@A3PZGI3YviuDch36qOtWzG@GIioqdOi7G4D8bkkHuHwBbf28VHIfcZMeg1q0ZQY8mp/q0m00JWajDfbdQhvtpJ@MQQzADB/LD1pHfPmP7euqctFit0x0gJRDeASkels@b2Wy1D7xlSgUiGV8XsSDyX3en8Led9fBjeah23RG9syQKE9XwqkHgd@Wb6gaNEnJUNmmC6zQ3s1qyVNlFXAAyH/7OYdJc6bSt9cX5lgxaUrkkvUVQnhntQ/D3slRJijevPJ7IxtZJE0lJccXWrlQ51VFp/VYyrjLrdQi/d/RwhUoTDyLm9NNSNaI2ypFVsb6qN6SAsAaltGHKQrSOQ0NZu1I/d5erOO4Cot33oWDMsISu2mCx5/iu0Th5WR@OyJ@WM5AaN@FEqkCTphMbHIFYdaTTpfT7cYcCsqo40b55oXMr4zd@I0H5ncNPfoSeqefJ0pyAeGsQZrrVkvUhR8cqvtlfgkKDV9sB1HAWbmnt3eLqCgwdl5XKVYqldACdtX1WL3fMpYCo@iKNtxjY7BgChrqHAsEVtukajFABxXUyh1nVWsF/1awZAmEegV4y9ROOvuQNLRthqkSubvGrbhNu0@c81p0APkP3e6VzNvfOrEn3nmUJtyOENXq1En7XHWk6@tNMTjVgkGBMudmFo4gFuGV0EeKcRJwsktrAmETU/6OA2zKYNMLTyHVXu8xdp2KjZ2WANKkwtNd9PNsSu2eASX7idBkOujPLIu2n61x6GcY2yY9UJFpDyZZ7adb3iNqUy2jTbozJ2ylxVOpSwtspKLBg8lcSrJZiiq2epTR3VSlFmfSrnTuGIfBLyfqgY5f0Nz3DUtLcBsDnTndruloMfYxC4sraVXNc8e6WuuFep0LidhlCHWBkf9UVAqfPlFjKaLQjGx8gtkWFr3mDwBti47IUWA1bS7MDNSiSGyM4pczevdntEA@LPKYYCyb10@jBKPecTDhhCMTCR9mUACrchdUQ26W2rpqmsqIoCnNxyShsMCXfmt36WH/7mYChMNgd7MS@ih/JDvV1MkP1s8VV246W7MqbqZxmTmVOx5afdauTXeO2MrhReLYzhfLBOCX19EHyi0jf1dWm8TUP2ctwowM0oLC5PkFKd0NKvUSJZ11ZQDbCMvyUeVokZwqbik1pP6NGNzKzk7CyCNGy4ijVhnO7nlqcfhDD5iu@pBe2k57ZFDhK7ENq7ApY5ZdVI@8W0bKquziWgi5cR/GuyOa85PJwEryzD1nDHQ@G@rDIlYhZmjM@1/boR1eQFjPZelBh3JNy/KJStORG9sPWVZCu8yQQMBPh6U5Sd3fh2Z9WTJp3BwvT2QHAPz7IcCxDvJSMNohuZUanrSqsCkzFdVVCYtgfuIykWvS2FipM90MFBC@yR3Yk1e54qULapXE3cJ@adtzkLApixybOASSJ7sTCNDnLgWp3OL88vCtxjp4hVHJqFddrZrgESWExCLn1CLuY8gfRmgyI4DFV6kpWa7LHNBXh89uaCrKyx5yZqX09TGaF4bqfWxw2p7irynUnmD@6fhVoLIFvk@dzm@NqvVtFLhxh6e4ssUp/91JT/Krsus49FOOrSKM04vonSUGcuAqlOEbY20oob9ihlBQTLLRA@Ch2jrP4CKXTTWVnzj7IvRC1yrSd8k7HyMqc28GXZIkmoEvHh4Mlpxsu9EifYe/920dtJeMsh4x0CK474T1r1Ez5gF9EZLH2AULAkFqeOVoVFWAq3wrCViUncalKxyWJqVzDE98aqChuo4ciC7dGFORnBZqz@x7l9ETWw9PD4fS33lfckZexAZmRamyo3GPifDAzfJh11FYzXCPK4arfMBW2Bc24y20YWyZg1/Jwvwe3zOWnGwi2DtkF5dBZSZ14jcwno9anPNJ@iE4ulEWSrfUbFbq0FkECRpDpnz2@@@TAoiM1dy2HVR@MbEa2X/BwSnk@QUiryHZ7dEiaYoEPl9pQV1e7HDvfbIWrFslDjiNzO0tXaIbs14VaeYUbFOZTGA0FdzrUdzHH7Q@O212XzncsrttcACGZeR@/OYLf3EV3Z9bJL1m85KkyyJLVTO/6rd2773Ndw85O5LRwQjP5rWeCoN7sFN4n436/QeK3KrIIUx0jZAItNdruDpjx3Uqe4TThNB1nSoy2Ew@wdaXB3sueNouMNcsspUVatyfojm3JFTiA2xbbedvNrr8p5O7CcmBxSnaHV0QpkS@cfMuc7NVVR1eTMZrhzbGZs073fPOk5aalK//ZoIXXuezsaNGBmxsHQzDJ4MlvpaytCpvhnGvDmyLpbmL5ruoWfugbdEdKu0nLzOqqbHeL3e8tETD8foTSg3ncNRkIoPKL48AUflp/U55UOxduJbRIeUrOUD21cp/Hzk7hTnXUWYX7X05m0je6dnzc6rmZ@rou5zJMiYLsRKopPe6kp0MDZ2kq59GpHRe616hc1DO@ouKpAWV@6JwqvHrmuxRdzXi5g9jDlJbFxicFW4D8nQ2s7WqReygqd/jGLTSKA148LWWI@9ImWO4@bHZjfflxTCpGgB7uX8@fbx/RrPglhEjgxZV11X/qQ9a6LentZ80QQnldUnL3co4IaX71Yvwwbb@YxMPmyqIHrUvpqVuEsBgxIGxqTACV7B6urZpevgmtt89mT1SA6yx3hAHvlr3emoXx7H0719hWk0zKBO8iSRS63axV3DM@XPGzPGU3wr1cxxhQsJ7BUQZ7xQmogz14IDXUGZWpmq1uBXvNu/N9srXy9Zq32aoqJjmRKwFZy6BbgArtT/YUXavgHRG/bJ22G8mpZyeSGwDmL5UASyQJYluF5Rxj0C1o09oppJNoyJX7FtPtLIASsHYJxZZ2fH3sfKarcbCSkiVTuvzpboQiH6GtHu9sPzVASnmytR8XkaTOgWyqhG2XyG02qUn55hQ9BQjmV@G8ivB1zZFo3TbWltj7bTVvh45DbpshujIfEdy/vX0rFH9LUO2sIRTHY6pqXdZ8fbC7YxYepVHoQdmupYQ2T7dFHfQmlqv7AzvfzXC/QS3MVJbe4OKIDW52US/uQ@7vls5U@CJs@pbpZxnPBtx2jrf6NSG/9TfdjiGUacnJRAUvuIsQr6JN1s6QL2GMNKy@Mdsi2VgCa/3K2FJNIAl7FCS95ygcZq3YBuCpPPf0ku41@Pbx0zSNbE26/@@0FCjlb/LVGod3KkjKFFnfDnetft3xm0vtfKnvhAKXr6xwdn9U0nAQRrWygfkpK371ovZMvkeKl310FoWxALWajKcqLnPQMfn8QvfWyNl@B8KhJl3IGbYcmdtfq3BzD8vlNdHeoYh42fKlHILXmWb6OMBSBqfGv62n@a5PS19scQXDuSm@/WgEyaFIke@wbRH8ulBsPnBroelkMqZZ1aH9RsTO9zYFATlwar/fheK/TphMs8dXy/umfO75YcolmebB/wc). Its program B is easily written.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84915/discussion-on-question-by-l4m2-send-the-pairs-in-smallest-output).

Answer (score 6):

## Python 3, pretest ≈ 3.198 · 10<sup>3085</sup>

```python
from hashlib import sha512
import sys

def encode(pairs):  # program A
    elim = [[] for i in range(10)]
    done = set()
    code = 0
    i = 0
    while len(done) < 10 * len(pairs):
        e = 1 << i
        for a, e1 in elim[i % 10]:
            if decode(e, a) & 1 << i % 10:
                e ^= e1
        for a, b in pairs:
            if (a, i % 10) not in done and decode(e, a) & 1 << i % 10:
                elim[i % 10].append((a, e))
                done.add((a, i % 10))
                if (decode(code, a) ^ b) & 1 << i % 10:
                    code ^= e
                print("progress:", len(done), "of", 10 * len(pairs))
                break
        i += 1
    return code

def decode(code, a):  # program B
    k = -(-code.bit_length() // 8)
    a_bytes = a.to_bytes(4, "little")
    s = b"".join(
        sha512(a_bytes + i.to_bytes(4, "little")).digest() for i in range(-(-k // 64))
    )
    b = 0
    for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(code.to_bytes(k, "little"), s)):
        b ^= (x & y) << i * 8 % 10
    return b & 1023 ^ b >> 10

def read_pairs():
    return [tuple(map(int, line.split())) for line in sys.stdin]

def test(pairs):
    code = encode(pairs)
    for a, b in pairs:
        assert decode(code, a) == b
    print(code)

test(read_pairs())
```

#### Pretest output

The encoder (program A) takes about 6 minutes to run in PyPy.  Its output for the pretest is:

```
31983609135966228809777741024866634396367955850954563312910243722966419655757435319862170247982609333805811315728884450895580799383047152743378820273077053884539894357668608677003723034054150072472679319590110643492810118920515801395958239291576592748237372467748241886558720871264342908155191777359585845696600370935487361341785211913110481040589139281898484188938846817560295768498881287225642023856190028544427590648046456036574330957328066402924125404073006144179946215625958643494081212962075340324684130280414625483652805036566339457267551141894682726365505972133784971174734160698976154775811488656096461968463830423074194023690503590590775033695214423998615444187716064686144001451215863398975347419967640878071667106313050954800893007781291647431510389526738768573353015452189679155051541561231146940706328809607485776138460159591319080343284358448724370020894125934538601889550086934233091980254236012141359542061770911092807766526451019824031548581065916355093797436687555279312288875998494044065641530299531661256941700326425163573657004343895103496724901715610405315696830871086538183435694121760474073023458471744226820280782007502797691083190318324487197753443963571848733746071847847503077912802000091614327968964141450181973360651625471354587026290724846906554164924720066533282988840115094797514460217879380690461261835733295861803705394151420199059533051945944829244868440580371672125590557347324783817602474773801825029895884776404639198926793779867410515553784121435319134307253638568331529787781235084628432871984360992875472633958491882569077293145250495277979952525973740358428525766027507530317692602517027217679810063987302625422496799748842451355136627998296037177558122844929449377522984595368107136303866235523533278732324181522202203636626264487517560120680389621562028772569157498411869721766672498939022664474767985892820170334179252554511620260319259569593256276255895000364202791049913505972232782566530566341223654980901733905002516092163056581626593518077383131036496001950185439305868415290006860241666136700655660075381115903744293277973930796274779653647714016073922883203769217980038066409200998466193202329090278491648479911508276027286548829602558975386937067679077276971208214625876007703346632539055994199462748282900998214486645162277623073498410220953186861172886747394992230973314265902007187446129816157393697305312624793190210450979525381906198852578619071224265649145441460469662250448218764499047348362548750003370944772956154662554023857705149861774126960045122299555516709305181620013892453158471100545618056605123335183465355868672237737792628988379889459029444873409805140995088383991356246685699313569301017907549835057806089472106637383136584875471496123974387658318450782138871582131161643221907721116143710024435066884630344739171885220542678102635637192667329306874983507141585026570891055701250722003923329858567937864129882737742073320064153568198296932909448928951903564049064190959836027425436414766746048788435990514173396582362591284614310722316033029018983309186148295917238363165751109139219360789557442877663768774219
```

which you can use to verify the much faster decoder (program B) if you don’t want to wait for the encoder.

#### How it works

The decoder expands \$a\$ into a deterministic pseudorandom stream using SHA-512, bitwise ANDs the stream with the code (output of program A), and bitwise XORs all the base 1024 digits of the result.

It has the important property that the decoder is a linear function of the code: `decode(code1 ^ code2, a) == decode(code1, a) ^ decode(code2, a)`.  Therefore, the encoder can compute the needed code using Gaussian elimination.

#### Scoring note

For official scoring, please make the thoroughly negligible “output formatting” adjustment of adding 1 to the code value, since otherwise a theoretically possible output is 0, which is not a positive integer.  As of this writing, the other answer has the same property.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), \$n \approx 2.088\times 10^{5033}\$ for pretest

```
a=Block[{aValues,bValues,p,poly,i},
  {aValues,bValues}=Thread@#;
  p=NextPrime[nPair-1];i=0;
  While[!DuplicateFreeQ[aValues~Mod~p],
    p=NextPrime@p;++i;
  ];
  coef=CoefficientList[PolynomialMod[
    InterpolatingPolynomial[Thread@{aValues,bValues},x,
      Modulus->p],p],x];
  coefval=FromDigits[Reverse@coef,p];
  FromDigits[
    Join[{coefval},8191~Table~Floor[i/8191],{i~Mod~8191}]
    ,8192]+1
]&;
b=Block[{i,p,coef,n,aValue},
  n=#-1;i=0;
  While[
    {n,p}=QuotientRemainder[n,8192];
    i+=p;
    p==8191];
  p=NextPrime[nPair-1,i+1];
  coefReversed=IntegerDigits[n,p];
  aValueQuery=#2;
  Fold[
    Mod[#*aValueQuery+#2,p]&,
    Table[0,Length@aValueQuery],
    coefReversed
  ]
]&;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVPva9swEP2uv8JroLSxwmKXjRWj4WYlsNJlSVa2D8IDOVYSMVsyslxSgvOvZ/qVLO0IBEf2vXv37t2pImpNK6LYguwrsrlD8e@beBABfR7pczTUZz4lTNqX4Kof8LbKqQzEMrgiML8Oah1sgv41AN95etc0VCrwg9JiTnghqvRjdPPhFvxas5JiEATkJylb2iAX/coVXVGJTWVoy2SJBr27b@tSK1J0LCmdYZ@UgQwURBH0tJaUFOnWf4f/kY08WZfsCRqVYvEHH8G5/69hLcoXyDqoK76NdocaPaOnRhO6UVPJKoot8SDKEoaGJuY6O6N4900UuzozFV6xpHUShsyk234Xgi7RF/1YsgWjXD2yRuGpVsdFxUipSbBlMB1KrVqPi6/@xfFbPw5NwI2rHASaoi3bZvBZi9G/zbHsMynRWIrqnq2YavCcPlPZ0NSENNCgTqKW7EEwjrc@t4Ofotto90Tyku7GpRASs/fmUwa3zHZvXrrMZhpsnIURyC4TkB/mwvQkbDkOnX47EI56g@i1x5Zjy2HdoVkrlDFqrleX8UIPnTvyxIJYiOrEe46smjNThCyMjlb43gvkF8k3zb0PTtyspfIF9WLrjCj9YMyEev0TRNiLddqls9@6g4fwkfKVWqcnML8Zp9XNThiD9u6eIZKalQdaNlf4YuIu3w4FF3CSOkgGzm6vTXV3EufYweHhNiGEPD7b/wU) (generate random test case based on random seed)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZxbj13HcYXf@SsYCzBscQvp@wXEBLRjCHDgKJJhJA8DBhhKI2kQcoYYDg0ZBPXXlW9V1R7JCZyLLR6es3d3ddWqVauq9ebq4fvrN1cPN19f/fTm6offXZT/ruWz/IR//j3/nBP/fPvl1c29/eHpbz59evv@zavr@6d33z79zdXx6rdP3/KX755@@tsnT/7j9sXv3r27vn948s3Vw9XFhw81p91bymkes8yPx4dcU165jbaPNSsflN5mG3W1dPRlH8xS2957jqP1ZR@sNVJdMx972wertJlGrenIQw/da/GAncZRWufPdS@@mVZbRy5Nbx08pI405jF60TdazbWlnsexp545WGlqeaZj6wllt1FGSnkfYyZ9kHNeZe5Sj7X1QUssIdXU@UbVImavsxS@d6zR7Qt9jMKq2tGrXpF5/mgjlWM0W0OvfeyGRQ42rA9qb9iK1xwtZ30wals599Kxnr6R18qbxx6964@tzNYmFu1HqfYENjpG3XMfWa/sI5e05lwHm9cuWs@tjVUnhtEHFWv3stj8gfl84322vdo8ahm2ytRS0yEdemLV03hDbccctotcM7YtMkxr/gT@Z8xZjty0C/46tzo5tAPz2ZHzhF4qlpm28cI7Vu9F@zTT5Vrq0JcO@37Newzt/Mjdzrf3VGbPiwPPyVe1OZ@8y2EOwJ4wdGe3R53TTJs57NWw3Ig1lYT5WEKxVa@U68J69ehm@lZwhpkmhsnV3qC/HCkfwww9cGkOoeI/9v2SRpvYfVSc1B7Ydhk7F07CvDivjsviDTyhas2ZPfS1Us0HXuNnsVrlOex62Wl1Tguv1HHbtsfMbQ5cJD5Yu@@x0@rHiuDCx8ro8tpl2yaQ1mInRJs5CO7BT3W6eZhLEor8CKft5pO4wtpEAnbI2Y5m5zpwh7qOnuyRI61S2WjCEvYNVkGg8F8H3ibTtaWfFH1huGlYZpqcZunmUiuVPVOeMoWMuzi6wQngpsVsNXkXPjXk1xbxefGKxHY4Hv2Cs6wsPXF6fry7lN0XgZDtg9LraJxh4YkeGCDCZNXrmNWMnfFzjrzjpbbKPIhNvsNPljl@no0jIsDGaYqyEk6KZXHbZjCzy2ZvhNfOzc94tYLFwQBzggn6YVzMP9wvJ2GRAa3BB3ZioAj/2zliewKYswZbz1qFfpE5jN550z6mPTKXUQh74uFY2fae9NqqZ0wDUGBoL7BlEbFdP@k17YJBCWnbR@WNYADY548Egksi@hRO02JaB9bXBNuAD@1j4P2Ewpi2BNbAifVN8Dhkt8lHay1O3NGT5YAaZXE@@j0LBErxvAM8s/MExTiydBA07mUdGAG2iVdzdUESMcYTqscj4bvxiF0JDi1iVyKHEzyqJwnMKEDfgw/0AyCFPzdcyD0mD@Kr4yQTxNcXwIfcBTRs2iCBuBmCFQ94wKgS/gugKyk5KGWchv8noi1WwFzcsiVCPJnh8WqAb8gfmi@KXWVex1ktc2w8JmEjgG5Z5pqbN@IPrNLcUm6tQGDZe7rHgGWYmh9YlukcLdYd5SiWZWoqFvIkkdGnGWoAKwAtp@u5j@xD9BFrljM2psfSQMRO3ZFwc7aEKk7s@2y8AcNO2wMvaDh9s@zrWCtkXZw8WcrDgNMinLFLKm4oEC6bOxnYcmBE4mbTORBjLCIaM3kaIw0OshyL5AmO5@ylpaWU38z4lnlZRQ0frgIAtgn07e7HC5LiDqzSkG@XRWyJAZTATtIJqdLCxvYFqyC74rPTk5L8iVDOE8zpfngknsRCtao4PaCNBIiPbXsp54Lxs1DJohlKgFd3VmWHBSYlwU4R7bBtbC25CaCrURmesEvmiCfLsnUW/bFtIbQFG6bmG@SE6QjCz0kq@EN3LAXUwJtCqHY7bpyF3Ipx22O0koUSnlqAPkdwuT2HiU95nmlNrk6@OoAVO7BCuA5FVze/ZYEsESCrQW7gNYAKFifkfd0T45LQgFNDbPC1CGNBvmTMhegkWJQkjDawygEEjE542QPJOyAWoYDj23niEWvKyzz8zIk4W0KFA3BOp1yVCeDt@AxFMG4yg0myAjjGJjccMzvrw/mLOBXpz9wIYAOsII4csZ0ox407JzEPT6lzKua1sbGc3mBe5QECqHkO5RfaSgZ/k4VoHw30YmduGiCdxMd6wVtzC2K2cygAMqDk8NfIV1Av8kbwl1pxBby1u7cCCoQEacH5C3uATrDYdWYWGCMUZ8oxnMjxgMViAUyg3aCGuMUNMKhRPyE0C2VVwzMNia0nXsqJNgtjXqFT73zgT0ycFyRFvpc98/QBgnFG1X0P54fz9YabGBgJGCAQgnFRDb1VbLEZW@yezqrgjPAAt20ZuB4rZ3EnqsJh4CgsHQByRsoyhEDEuoUd1AOg5eD1FnceTMUZAh9BvfEzKOQwNlaDk2QdIoTRaS5nB3WmtMA89tDaelrQNeUo2wtAgnWgINMQBnaINTesdtmfIVULXkA2cAIIdCj@G3m5eKwLBWdVKJvxKB4ocKxesO9D0/B64ASvkCXgnoooUHEZPxSlbaSDERRGIQIsbz0hWcpjdVNkHTPYC@HuhAhez4E5B92qmpoRL4tC/A6oINeHa8JNiCJgETgxtKd@w9lZmKiY/aRtJSBKsmM40@Kf94YP/CLSMXXDu1uQB50XOHU0C32SFc4KdQqaSy1WVV0ZQBkdFE6LFx2ekJS9KFvg8v7nQnHBaYDtwykplsnAbhIGds/MJMQE9sI3mic5IQMxwWEWt@0ADUknKwVUKH70hWGuDA3ZhTS7xSCLczvlB5CFVdojYLlkFeqiZqsWs2sL4ku4OLRjBr5CQGEsy8zQYpUQiScY@uC4k9w9oxQGZQjZppC1HwiohoqxFWDfCHjwAL8gfThwkF5gpSA3b3JcBqXZwgivIgJJi0vGbYbtBD9WhtHLNnYcLBNc1KoMNYVMm6ybTuosNoe15CNuiYqndzG0w9kiLkFpzVoCF6Ba8F5SaT25NawaLKIgJ8htZyq1BSf7JEYwUdLkJPvm7nUoFQIZmgJtOVPGhRrBVFS6dONvqlugT8CsYw0APYfixSs2nG6L9sMQHCGh8rg7@zbkwceGCl2QfZsPKJqzEetukEAiXpASFu00Z1jSUyboFp9ETZHKoORuVetQXQuQRwlJVTQrLkAkmZmIHyUgACNSJvjKbxS/3Vhx3k0/H3JCpwsJCpdFvg5jrFBLqhblbQtWUo5YzohiXyarnJwlaeddfCOBdMTu9kykGrSprt7mgSRYuRxJOznNwn@H6q6zdlda4f2kBYJ1elwAK/hridqNigVIIVM1SshQCEC5pbScnCQN5UyV1oExsD8sXVSc@zOreBJQRWIxlyMFQKtVA/myiUJiR8jo1V4WFedkcMDtHon7VCv/tuskfIHgwq@B9xahNmBvcINisYVj8paponRGdaeCFA9iYwZscgXRs6W6ymwxRaWgXzDlEuUeWYmPOJ7s5IwA5cV1h@zAD3gPeZIaI8gZLq54wyncCbeKp6ZabbkqQCglVRGxUPJFUYQWuaHlZSq9hr1YRbMDYK9gPFuBbrsyBb9QWi7BjcE5KIv4uhNCCEvKQ47abBFNGE6k4UjAh6sbdVqu4AxdDeE8SXNkgerCAXC9BNqk3OzJTujZlU/NVvi16h4BbngW6ZgsDCtqwWBgdMAwiT@7CFSxDksnHLazomGAq5eCo/YT/IzsI1I/nNKofs5SszykCTz8Chc9lheNoiNwohYRI9MsAsZ4lddwVAV4o@idsbmq@gteC2NxWS/rjV2Z9LBVkeClP0IFwH3T2ESNCR8Q1yu2LGGPwFWp4jIO8cMih5RCr8jkd1vI5fX5buQfgP@ovgYyDYFIeBgK4EQENYl5n4mfNZAEFS/umcpegDSFR1SJ1NecDlwg3F9LAMyod3EJewUxrbSuos3KH56M2y1JbO4kMOallMq2rE6ccm7JNsSLnTCZr5J0sKQHMRGOYwHCodkARYJ5nafHJFBNUjdRYPphKOXC@laoAKLAOLr4jFXkBfiinAXzTslsi9VCP/AqyzSQCmy/jb@ns/oBsjrpzpgAWZ88xWckO3sFFETP3Ozb3ZB4xkOIuSi4IXzkBMwjgdOSLlYbsg04vzzfbemVVbidw1b8BGKLH1rMwiBFejlF4mee2YxCXbqPs8tGOSzeQ5hb0ZxxWpIBjBF7ui9jBABmKO79tWAs5Atvd8cTE@ec58l6q5hZgjnzZ9sJqUK5ngTkwixscdmREC6uwsA9ZmoUKm5/EmRS6V1CncLUuCkxI8/zEqCo0FGJVVyhlkiLu4O8bfrWqWKwj2pJc02tEIAbIjnLtT5BmvzIlR6sS7pQJW/cr6k4VewYbGBoql@8ncNwGV6PBiKxW@yh2SbEJJxGU7lugnuf6gNUX8klKct5wdZEvVXlBTGrOk9pN7x1enRwvgAmBCZkOhgTTNj0R5MsMimOdC6RM7KcsEr0HFgevvAh6bWGVFsE@ypl8LvhOC@aK/F/uOFWVfyw98NBgH8GXyVANweijSkwB5bz/kEBVkjjJIxAtzUUCxv6mMJvSZoqVKvzA2BiVpePDdVhgeqt6DTzdDQkPORgztJw5qlqQcWAUXs5TFYJrizqj5RehYeorHfRjKIK9HvMiDIUnmE1uZcPa6lr0YN9ciRKA8Mw3VkRXi8lULWbraJuKVrUiVFPKzfBCKCgwVA5GSo3ULU@BrUaEsnemgI4loQWduLtHhKTxAmpqrYKiCKMQ8nJmztKyhTITczI5SGOsrlaWKOTwu8HPtRc@mEjWGeIiRsvyoQi6Db3Dj5RVU137JaijQWFATc4L1DCZO8mzUwqNQG7nXCohsgqORybxEClhI/IsthRLsC2pqUK3FRdEXXG7BVVxUMd2CvEINmSl7Kv0oIGQUZItJDS5QFNdSWiqg/cuDitkZ4aB1bFGRvGbsYhAUywkUolaChwqoSmxO5Ke@JVeIUafIZT2GFLtGohRKjtQUZQSym6FkmFEckBy1XPh9M0yR0VpXo/A6Aokd6UceUC/aT6SxUqxRbb3nFaIDLItM7zlDAEEPAt4rWdApTKGICqphMNCT9Fh721ssg2rPgy8QicgR0V9blmCrGDN@DgLNPYtdKuqhjvKfJY3jEhEtnJIV/X2YnqbVc6yJikVXVroqQhwil7pGq6LgpGEC/d1pR8G@YBVKFREZJw9ZukDkNzhtMJ9y39tgSG86MCzrPMGv1VXtzld9v7c2zU1uXZS/qMhAEFnKEwtRs4BLKsw/kIxSGHSPh0Jw@kXJYOaY8PIKb4kGiR7B8hqjRcTSTugbl7Z5XLxVM12RB@atVJPduGSeVyCpkSyBZkqpfsJTjrwhpUzZSqZsAlArhNsfKXUC1BY2GpyyV8lgHEkqBA/ljogDLg4MdwGW2YKKbCtPpPcEZ2160rF0X53NhGzSjXloyBsHp1n2co8E2sX/bRM4gG9X7JzNEU32oeLgkYzTtL8EkRBp2Rl8NCAckaaj544wgqxbdYl0tcaqgWikkply7iQlOW0vl6jJqstmfTIXhZ3pS0eDHO4/qounKE0JAQbICjhAS@Cz4cw1RXsHAIl5dmle3DJJNqif3oskYZtpdRwPmWUlUCWzNxyltnl3O4bivtTqXDCt5PgmAllK0rYE85qkq28hKoqp/E7ueMlKC2Jd8twj19AaJGNihSiJbrJEXlozXRQiCkQANylFxd5oJQq4MIufLefFHnji@dHqwGsEjaPLkoliTUqkub3pynGsc5xIC98U2KSfxCndDuvZSuLjMU4mwpcABqbJailpGHPChFYE31X6zoh1tRwWy18F2oVME5FK2@FTCIGFBN3z0Ha@RiqCTg3J1GUxYJEeD2rjNM9cIFXXGK6o2JLuxzKKOR0pvKQnKuF5nqZHLuawbdb6qRoBcYaFtFaNydMjOfsvgUExlqExfnebwwqaGNhaNbhomX@asjF2yM51HVO9ck/0juEjPYUWEM9ZZILN3CRk7T1OmVAmMbq8ZwQP7De0JzKTcRd47oJJ0NH1VrzOVpSVJLlVEgnbpUMhV1kg83DDVjwIAdYwJF6EyhlaRdeBOfVfFCHM/rLOgNJJklmiGr2tAURWoRTZdgNTuxtzBre/GnziwQASHy6h38gpj1GmooTiNWTg0YdLVImswafgAEslFqqrtpCp7riFByOPgcZx@yqvkCTVfqSclHTSTSyRuj@oaACwj647gLpdqckiFa8tZJ0oSNyZ0jJLyponJJpfU0oZmbrueSaTxuJbpaSj07pmr9ZeMrQUmbcDClHmRPmy0S2c6BliltB54g6PSBla6ahvglqSZPJC4P9xNwBoGZptqPQf5ALAndqotc0KSWUPdQoxq2twp0qJrCl90v@AWI0VRgOzkolAM4JPSvxSCOmh/Z1X5X94iLBGVka65fYkE5gpRZT5IS6@FFRFBxwMZsQ@MzQY3hH3gL3yL1dId4aTAaYoi5CRGpYgK/K@nZ5nKs9brMGHPqK9LmfZn8DvRNMniOKBS/49iaa@tsTEKZiZwhAU7r7gpbt7GBqVCHParm9p4BlEajGCM8QSrQ7JBlNWiiibCkMT8OW0iFtTY3yT4@aJI6m6mIeihQoGweJfdQ816KHxnBxz@2BBKNIDljHOITRb1aT4/ANdBMJYZfOVxJqlDH/ljxgFnUagJsHJo1NyXE0nyBF3TgwvIedCjpbFtKZjtbV1lEqaukglo5X1fDWYKzPVMtJG87cF7efxnDOnLeQVC9mG1ahtK4eu0j3Z334AE7dBwCZEoEcGm9D@XsbM1Gf0fD9zFMix@Q1VTqzLOBKcLZ1OoD/Yc3U5QshuLWsQAHqVpIgdA4pEm9Uv6L/iUeg1@JjhcvCaQ@AZxVQ0R@4Klmm/E4p8jgSFtgovBwRbdqCAAnIKF4xh4DYoF/nCHGuXcVZCk6Mhq3US7Et5utAuMawY55DpEolo1fU@0WH9jJFpTgYosMwwuGoDR5NwVuri5s82TAs238Kg@fUsCy0qRWNEY4fQEeGeNMzgJ7KdnE8DbhjkTRFZXqHztbhAxqHArqt89e8NK4DdTF8yYJBVar2RtvKnBYJoeUHGMmcBDbKvs0W0IpcDvCqZy2VBdREKneb6gVgKi4opfDIrS8RVq3QY@6RhJItmsZpGHyXtdM0vKJEjUis9Tzkly7TWqpDh343jFiBK5octFzEts0KQG6lfwRkjfwrNDfYYF4vQZsQprCtASblhG6jRr725XxULOA3AGx1E9cUWmS@qqNWwW4DaUL8YEcY5@Qy25l3nTySfJuEmHyST4nhSc71VBHDkLQJR0YDvheycdEtioqPyCV02ph5uBbSztVnR5NGQy7wTI2ExUyJ22TpF1TIMPNRQUA1O6YNhXuiHAqxJySLVXAJr92B45sM3AKuR6C4dSkmU7NRSvWvSmcKdxdftXk04C8aJTEm97W79DYYhRlVVlwbIso5/ukJ5LmVEc/5rwojoC5maMjrSJYncA2TypBrPEbsS64xIyhChMMNDnpuqREQQ26Hd0Zqy1tCeec5epESEHqz3qawo@LNDdcOrghexNpqqdsiyE1wSdQyt5jJHNSLw4Tj12FJW8tjew8wvHUbpudVPI2EXulOs7q0HsFycIljFdYjWMfZ68isoFCy9KOPGZKK/TRGCKxkdtHDwmaIjXruTvmtcT5NTSk2bnmU77LGo9y7GjiEYsSCoa1@dvUgsjrXphIxde0oyQ1eyNlSRN12DGlkVXv79RFkaJxsjWoSol11u8SrKd6rnygb5Dfq0Z@1OG19AsH2FKw8B0XCrMmAtVKCSVYFEoDgjvmNsAIyXpCqW2oxO/V4u0jFBjxn6ROtCoZJ@9DJUdSWukxMkT5NYdSspclkyUsrdLFDfWAAQTIBafjo6bqraqncI6JbTUUtgZ65oyekYR3BXyuXqdkpeRmqrnXKdJUPc83p9dwKkm9zSEDwro0DKBqyptlWEfMTq1pSzOaayQR9mBQVUqVCBAb87FAdTyHY5sz0KFeY7YDNhcgrxUVT3iZLYpIUFu1qtwyvYsVUiBI3irnHIB6y4qPOHPggb/XwIN9AN2VAi3W651G2QXk65rKi4FJjZao2xEznJQyIOpUc7j5HI2oRa0iFz7IRxWtjKyhruFyE2WEBBX1lbwhLQlc6p4KLE9vKlflSB5QWiiZSE2faVRa0VSkGqdoOWdlQP4jx6g3QKtFjTmDO1A5DbGqEjO0Uic14MpfVxdoVNprLsNnjvhmKji41GD3RBwb4Kk2suUTWoJf6vAUvLlqgEGtfJnT@4bwdLAv7ZgvJmFb@hFPDsFYHb5l1wG8@FTYwoqW2hYlxg8URVaoVx@CFXqoi91qjCURlBnGe/jUs4pJ6SkAp3M5TaDA@Gd0nIGgrrFX@Ylx4E40Wtaty9X2rdleMZ5o@EAUrF@jOVuvp0jpcJaUop4iWVKFgCBehEilU2CPGoO9un9AurUZIu8yqQFKgKUUw9tqd1p9WmNMArhRiaZ3dJ8WrFL7qEElhY8YSS1qBR6zRD7UNL6k8OnjWFKNmt1K8EElTalAMaAQoVqqeCU9lOhcZXuf0kaQQY2PknFgv1GuQpqSCKEiJNK29J2ietX8aoAlUBJBXD57W6Co5j090AWSoCqnG/NagJfuOshY0weEq9ReqXYu@cP0NFppXDtokPhLqW38/AnOR7JTDTcjxqRTAzoUHt4VJeNL6FDfJ3oqGiEWnESxLg1ZjpEeB1GX3T0pIxqnasNIlYBMz@GxTubVdmu0hrIGPJuXeTErpmkzkIk07mNcAEuVi0qFc0FxbHEjm6CNcQexfJGDHmlcymAqj4MEmp63GagRg1jFxs5V9lAB@XWDpB4jMeJ4gSd0Uk8@mYKmEtRqVXHiA7OZL2QdyiwhwmfpemoaG5XaGuvRJYjYB3jSNB8yY1I9Gz9fGPRESg1l9VTUr/cB6UzoW5bAnF4skj81N6q2pyuUQ7xS2ojzClC58kzwOiZFuuYxqyamrOi2fglwU71R19WHI5G1E8TUEsX3UjQPiSCJ5Zq38E6CBM6kCwi4VvMqToOYUimPUqIUoYIl64NgMX@7VN5oGtb1dFXg7Jw8Zhl8afo@SahdXqRrxADAUTfQg3INjVNUjfoM35bGjDWgAin16ka9ha0o9OF00qacG7u0YGBd/Eo5Z48V8lmXqpxiWNBmObvaVvGNbLlx2B2XmJaQ/gP3G1Fb6E5G0kBK0B3px1WzCo9dsSwIVNo/ildh7HTpQpcmKX3QkrOpmhLIXnzMIV385Bljq7uoBlZ2DJTcpsF9AtB8ToOhkm0JLy/7JJWpskyRKLHkIF@ZvuxNZ74IbdANFp9M0SM1vSbtPeQGcXyNmbh8P9WkFtmkTKteIDW1e9U/9JFFlTFUVfW8XVCSNZ01QmB1nAY/OXvl4h6JEQ5mEp7neyASkJT67BiRJUfB686Bp6leEtBB7l0@qNUlC/L0Iwd4Jd1zsjLFk4V8FNo4Ir3YLSvrDqyQovGWpkGWc5w66U6WODBAH5KgCmTNctqqYbp4gF0uKDna4sQS9cE5SgFvhYztoak@L39JG0p6@3xJsSmfrnknL/Jsjp/N2AUDm9Qj3fAem5L03jq/AD81ihstiJx9AMCHf03SgitZN9/VIN1QAsjVCveJ@CYuBK4Xjx5dWNQswjplSNlOtUYNTb0nrUIo4jJL1hCshlN23C@STinGtjRy42qCBgKbqg@/OCHupUkuxXCwQEhH16iQjxxqPo1tVF2siRuCW1OvADe4YDovnJsz1y0nvxeheRCQZKg2cJ6ebIxetjgvfGmqcevyTkyrd5EGCD3f8HVSFGyb6d6ea9rS7UjdCIxxvqymnE2qOLGcmk8S9lRnNjbIgnt2H10QrZzqKpIXRggvc0jXiMHybKN4qVgjyiu3qhEOIhNu5LNfU73ybbfOPGg1MTXUDFwp7pAME0eF01EnTXFPqTmu/o8iVi6kKd7q1myD7njEM4fm4XX5LO5JwJd1GUZjA94s13RTE8RFS1i3L8dUzyHa67o@MqEHmhJPpyl0A8wosdFEFRMTUIh@e1atMZWDjp1CCNOdPglXjiVVxgWN1PewQwfr@PP4Wf2Ujj9wC5zVwIek2tQhEI@x8Ygh0NbNw@ajREvTsuqKhk6gayhLc4s7JkE0hqyRvhSdFPWLi0T0GeCgBpw64OoxRfdGQwCaNHehslqLmSwv3THmAtRHthqnxy3Aqs7J0CR4DaY5lEz1zMA8Uti06dTp45SanZPSzJn6FC8pDx9YJVItFqGcU4I/84vuQw39iANwzALRdGenP97TpczUFbloEiVdiFIHjawX14JEcsrjoDfEfWtEUzPyvYXQq6uD7bHu0TVeHttHjKFRdqZqGZoQccxqUGBpnECp115UPuo8pXNSQ/ax2cXQjLYmO5pVILPEjY5sl4/i7pA6h1OZMnrbSkJJNNxTkO5QSJCWp/lItdKwTWf5TQy1CaGz1Vq50aJPmnlQi95YNgxCPWRBRdwKUqtLxzHj5vYYdsH0KC5VSMpURz1FglDy1@R199sGNjOuAS/eGJKsCuGpWyqRvZcJw8Csf0HidTJRi/hx/W4t@bZuyji4aM5AEyuQVJ/@6ppeBdxJOT44J2GjuZahRXWNG8PgUlwWaEua@TZp2sJHXSxNDEVWE3lfdm8sDheQUE9WZbKnH11KkshA5o3bx9SA4Kyuo/s2BbJbERm9IAkuIhn7vPMyNVTQVFfEGI7EaSKknjfHlIl5Bm46Y@gpqaEt3bd69bL1Ek3cKrW69A91SlPDdFG@dE37a/QjoiVrRmna/UKfrJJGKzgRKTQnMalKE7DkwW130gXT0iUcZHHCOlWJxcCz5BkV7KzCL9HqZn7XlB/BYpINKCARFrbnCUvdHnCjB5EV3AIBWSuIqTab2CRT@MXsIR0KAKihX@rsNURDneOSMPCsTkwN/UATVVpPeyyBm8206y6az0mQBPitXS71Jrz0S4lddvknaoasf2nB2Teedul@WRGSzqTJrvSBy2NqXJOXVX4@Jk1dHcw1JmaaJWqpK3FdBCvBW8Ae2MDw@NeQTT9DY2dr9ejOno8wUD2upjIxJoG22EjRlKoPASt7qQEplC9xPZXg0ARDVOpAvHixumTT@YTdgC2mkzi9IBthCbzjJFqEoqSuuD0@lYu2Lpd47GEXgeeKXraOQZ0Z3eGb8W9mECSpCglOpJvE/McK9lekB0l/Pnv2mqzG8EOFDS/5@NPVxe9f3339P5cfrv7z6vX763fHq/jvt8fbu9d/O24@Hk@ePv2/f/vx4i/f319fffPik@f87duLL65/ePjy/ubN9aX92zE@yy@f31wk/d1/fX/z@vryn/7w/u3rm6@vHq4/v7@@/uoyHvfjv9998@Pbl3rD3z3lxdvnz57d6Ocv9R9f311/e/Gv/Me3N1/fXN8@/Onm3cPll6zu9u7NzdVrHnJpT/jj7cP1Pau@eri5/e7nv7@Mtf6/TRw/@JufPuUR71@/f/fZv7AY/u@Hx9f@9er1xef3d2/@cPPdzcO7yz9f//X6/t31C/0VX9S3fvG39rB/u7u5vfwQv/0oppl//MvVq9fXP37@@u7u/vLmn/XRy@PDje1ef/j40n6p75aXz/KTl79@/uTVeS43nIS97vbw9duB3F588ln@exvbMz7cHm8/Xnz1/u5Bhvrz9Zurm9tvru8vb/3hz@1LN88u3j4Pm1/Yav7BKR43z/KjKWLv31zIzN9d38emb8MOvriv3l/f/@3ik2KWuXsdB6MT@uTTX3zj2SeFn/3azW/WuUzHn65vv3v4/sUvvhae8cu3yydkoJ/8X7xycfVC/3aVJyz79uHyV1/4v43lx4unvzq@eOFfefnkH3qv/dT/JS2Xry7962Hldy8vLi7i@y9/@l8) (pretest)

Use `InterpolatingPolynomial`.

Due to the [Birthday's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_Paradox), this is not as efficient as I expected.

Comment: As Anders says, this code doesn't work for `{{0,0},{1,0},{2,0},{3,0},{4,0},{5,0},{6,0},...,{1022,0},{1023,0}}`. Either add 1 to the result or map zero to an impossibly reached value

Comment: I guess You should give your pretest score, not the code size: `Smallest average value of the output of program A over a fixed collection of random test cases wins`

Comment: @titus fixed. ''

Comment: @l4m2 fixed. '''

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 1.873x10<sup>4405</sup>

```python
import sys
inputs = sys.stdin.read()

numbers = [list(map(int, l.split(' '))) for l in inputs.strip().split('\n')]
def encode(numbers):
  output = ''
  def allNumbers(numbers, a, b):
    nonlocal output
    if len(numbers) == 0: output += '00'
    elif len(numbers) == 1:
      output += '0'
      output += bin(1024 + numbers[0][1])[2:]
    else:
      output += '1'
      l, r = [], []
      m = (a + b) // 2
      for item in numbers:
        if item[0] < m: l.append(item)
        else: r.append(item)
      allNumbers(l, a, m)
      allNumbers(r, m, b)
  allNumbers(numbers, 0, 2 ** 32)
  return int(output, 2)

def decode(output, key):
  output = bin(output)[2:]
  index = 0
  def peak(n):
    return output[index:index + n]
  def skip(n):
    nonlocal index
    index += n
  result = 0
  def findRange(a, b):
    nonlocal result
    if peak(1) == '0':
      if peak(2) == '00':
        skip(2)
        return
      else:
        skip(2)
        n = int(peak(10), 2)
        if a < key < b: result = n
        skip(10)
        return
    skip(1)
    m = (a + b) // 2
    findRange(a, m)
    findRange(m, b)
  findRange(0, 2 ** 32)
  return result

output = encode(numbers)
print("%s.%sE+%d" % (str(output)[0], str(output)[1:10], len(str(output)) - 1))
for (key, value) in numbers:
  assert(decode(output, key) == value)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZtLj13XcYXn51ccGBDYbTPyfj@IaJhpBpkqGlBmKyHcahLsVhD/euX76lzqZcaGZd2@57F37apVq1bV/fiPl//@8FR//vn9jx8/fHo5n//xfLx/@vjTy/P5jR@@fn559/7p608Pb9/d3R/H008/fv/wye@@fXz//HL349uPd@@fXl6fj18/f3x8/3L36nx1f39//vDh0/l4vn86r2fxlE/vP97df77oP59e3X93vHv44Xx4@tuHdw93t@fevznO88NPL9zDK1694pMXvX18/Pfrgs8Xvj7fvj6/j8vP8@nD0@OHv719vN0Zf3v/w/n48PTLc89vvjnTm8@P/gvPTulVXPjw@IVL8/Xg83c3vPqnv33//ukup9LOv5y3u79N332bv7v/trz57vb054cvPCt/ftbj6/OTxvzuNf@7/e1H/nD3lmd@f3/@9a9nuf1Zk75/efhRq97e9vnJsV2/4/Xnv54/vuE43n78@PD07s6/3v9yWSzn/PSlL39j48ew7pe@@cSftftxfvFM0uuznH/@81mLV3x6ePnpkx7wcndtnW9xIQ/03UOc@uc///3hH78/eQ17ffhsyvdP7x7@l2/SzSU@Prz9@93TzQFub7ru@DYufXPdwMF8d7vj@e944NMfXSYuuzzmuuGb8ynW/vzT48tv3vcDX//H26f/erj7kuNdl392vFhbDkfCaz4f0ucvyu2LX785r7WVX8/p2tDxm0P7fy99YpGa@Hppug8j/8Yt3uIQ2Jd/fv/m1209/f553Peld1/fXV990St/Z5Wbw/z6t8@u8utfvuggN@Mdv5z@HzDh@PjJDf7pq@evv3r@t7989e5P51fnHYjyi4skwue3n/Ob7J@M6t/8@f78lzPf3x8G0h0meX3@z9vHnx7u/xBQb5@fHz693H3BRT2365aff6457d5STvOcZR65prxyG22fa9aj9DbbqKulsy8@zlLb3nuOs/XFx7VGqmvmc28@rtJmGrWmM4957LW4cadxltaPuhfXpNXWmUs78uDmOtKY5@jlqK3m2lLP49xzHYNVpZZnOnc/ym6jjJTyPsdMR8k5rzJ3qefa6WiJV6aaOt/WecxeZylcc67R@bKPUVhDO3tdR@aZo41UztF4Z6997MaOTzZ11NobduDRZ8v5qKO2lXMvHbvsI6@VNw87e99HK7O1iaX6WSp3spkx6p77zOvoI5e05lwn2zvYem5trDrZdjoqFuxlsb0Tw7i1PttebeJJgxWllpomP9dRfQZPre2cg9XmmrFYcduteSf/GXOWM7d88FVudXIAJ4bh2Lizl8q@eTwfU1u9F/eCUXItdXjByZU17zHc25k7p9R7KrPnxaHl5Bo21s67cN48pmC8zo7OOicGyxzYathkxApKwjC8srC@lXJd2KWeHWO2wmHONNl2rsf1xUj5HBhv4HoYtXLyXFnSaBNLjopL8Zi2y9i5YFn8La@Oe3Ga3FnTkVlrXyvVfHLi2na1yv3sa2H5juXxIo@MjY2Z2xwccHxcu@@x0@rnCqfHM8roethiY7j4WqyYGOB4OVxu8YzywIUIDi7HwTo@xFGuja@yz5wx9M51cJx1nT3xoJFWqWwmsVO@5a24Mf934iNHa8uLi18ON86S0uRUSscVVip7pjzdaj0WhzCwKU5VsMPk6fjC0P@Iu7x4bGLZGLsenEllkYlz8JB2KbsvXJX9Y5Q6GqdReI6OS0xO1rfOWTFgxhs5to5PsaI8iBW@5@KFc@bZMDiOP66tlpVwKeyFizXCe5fNDnD7nZsntVrBisQhxzjBGEyGQYd@NHHbDEQMPmJ9Ipj/dg6KO4n0Ndhc9q39yBi3d56@z8mDchmF4MNjz5XZXfJF1Xu55SD09yKqF/HT29Fr2gVDEVyst/IO4hCE8UEAW0lEhI4@iS6N39cERQjeYw48FGcdk1fyTqzfN44tBLbJH9ZanJrYxMuJ2bKw9jpYDDCFt5xgB@cCYmD@dOLS@kYnhIFBogeHFATwfe6sRgihtDnRXXHeduyKV3MWZxVmMY/guAcf80Ew86lx@J52Hvh954gnyJkP4jN3A5xtEZT49DCgDTvCvxKCC0ApKQkDmQPnf8QWngyS4UYtEWoJU@J9wMvwPJtLYO2ZF2D3hQNy2on9Aygc1jE37@A8WRFupPvpqixwT08b3MB8XAo@dw4Im41y4r2cX4nAA4JHnxhhENAAGGdkjgCziQgiAMzdGBPrEaI7ddFmc0IEDu7mXhpPxVyTtfLQhmO2yEpimJi1ODtwXUfF8gQWu05FI4AkOdwAEMP0xMZmWznidSxiCxMI@iSLQT5gQdwpNrLilpbJD5g5IiPx1hreVg1CtgLA7O4hgVIcJysCX3ZZ@LyZsAQyAcUkk3BpVk9OJfPgX1Mg1w8IqjyJ9O4xANiJRbmGOAdAhESBZ2xeg5UxZxYHiCsSI97XWQOGBwWSwV5MuCx3u7gm5HHu3rlL5qAmi2BNxQ9ti3mEAObjW3B1Gr3cBiBznl2cAj6I8kLgkB1wecKvYLJ2ix2wO@FXBYARD3VNDgVfEKFb0yFB@JOAxviF4Bl6PahutmE5gEaNVE4WJ5yxIoHnCicmA/6BKhAQ5CqiF/iSyNVEC64szJI4WdEgDEfH7XkMeA0@4Kw4J@fCia6pbxgScfycEI6MSeUoonsmmLaIR5qMjDyDC/FG8usGX08QgaSBgxY5A2kCBwBCAAfIDwfFyXBkOF4y55pw5jTyXP5YJnOMJpri3M0cw7UuOYNqiZDpo4EVrN@NA48kCNYGjnGsRFDHyIAcQCDINBAeWgHuRsaulcPEt7q@RVjitECrGZu1kk5Z2LpQGdZDQp8erNSEGxcLA5CAycMkRuwmDAWNEfNYFGsYYjRJoCdew8k0QorHenKdjz4nYXtSs/6SRew@wAssXvUXHBT@0huHDAAYmqRQQdFEe0w5TwvO0wX/KnTgvuAgr8VdWCNLuRCLrE1mZpGEvVyK1xr3xBzBQNIFwjg8n@zBYwZOg@ANYoh3QING8IwauTh7HNAeaRmnAMGD3rJ5HlVbTwsSIq6zZoKYvZN8yTQHLAcrbXgYyAB94W9NTJXMELhGYSNbFWNOrJnVsMIsUFgodfBWroR84JuEMqfaD3iTvg7ysJ1DEtYA1RFJWxcG6rZ3JpIDK5mSSLbJK2CUuDC@ifHlT1t23oJUEBn4CqFK3gtXIiPj4UAPoQxuUhfgkixDksHFbQvcEH4iG8fi3/YmL/4ScZiv4YUt0qe2BxlOXOQA3nEt6EHQMph@lcEHJEBsRD7z/ymMi/bQZfilnwr0FuuCk0Myxb4zcJZEmm6@Im0kMI1c20wIxiZey6EULTZAHMAYlzVU9W2/pBrgPPsupKAtCypyFTGWmGZF3AorA5Ph4Kz0kKm0BU3DmYVJtsnXuDqGIF9B4CSyiTuJeZxsks1mlE5ENwHUDCAuFRiGVH8FbDbCjojkXIFfwxZohk@BhDxdrAP3WOoIbyAqSB5Lk1FJsHNYIo7c3DnmZUlgj2sAlcSCTT5KF8GTn2AJT9idVvyxyzxOOQ9HSgHGuyMyIRKwNFJNvdgfvI/4p2Aj2Fi/5ZihvC8CAIcilUzyEvHs@iep0Hpjyeg4/IabFylzPzSQ5ieHydnIqjBxvdlaAEfZ0lDypBgEvcQp2RnxjmcMiyNQEuA/jKsc1A87kWlIRMPlmdRHpAfxlPyDx7Fyak1THfXOsBoCFqMUgYHPyiHi45gAzxa4CddIKiAXVxtLhCLZtXnb0G1MmQlSkiUWJzwLagRbNpMROkC1OX1EAagxKmcQiUtOwbcJRCGOtvhtDdOsvgBX/D/chDSWJBF42pDXX1WdkMz7gFZCZ@q3BDS@VaImgCkTzGA7xW2LehE0WSarJBUYZhULsIhtmAzWK5ZuPqnKBoAGQBk3AUghfjJuF0hc4Ndij/VDliZiZ1xm60EcfI1yYlsV8yVOj/8BlC0CgIoai0CVcSEoGhWMJc2MisFyhrNn@UCIRyntWHJ39jolC1ALGF2JAgIk5w8YO0s6CBheVXeUnlzKs8klsNwgHTiiUcCh6jZbkt6sApZVIk6e5LKxKPC2GDFFxyFbUTs0bMFbGyZlP6AlS4YOqi2QXU1WJVgceEKalkdKbUjSKQ/dinRLQBM6@D8uQPBa1dYZaMtpWP9yLiQEsLRaRAJ/SxAkGWXTgtjUzTbYAf@TZwtk4REkKbIT2b9FzoajAG6kwGxhX9k7i8Rht9l/BJD5GlCKi/EOUFuiOUzhVlpZJcLgIhjwB1wKxsdOTcPk/hb@7MYX7hy8wdoAhor/SFfgJ1V@DxMjSyu5ZN/RzTRgDrdudSBSIvi5jiBxuDZIZi2QFV0II0myJTq@zYKG2o18X1/Z4oTV26ZQBfR5qu8EowkO3JdI5PgJL9LVvlIg7yRZ6M16kmgP7EF8o@KgCsPW5MRwUV8JcFAjcaQ8lugyyVkOQLd5Gq6yFEM8YnjdMuGweGqOqRNalOPNnBMZogLWWMiAItJwCKAtKnLCX8D0XIwSoI8UF0Xi1LgmIxjMirpQuoY7mr@p2Cii2Y7YckkcWx5G4sUbwGhSKtbcwSrTxbaBiE5iICOS/0B2/kJa4LGkXp9E2Zp1HCKL8yUSoiiDvICrbF5xiXSEPYY7BzGXmWGrGFVxMIcduBgqhucQQXAgKRrngW/PC/sp46zmZUeN8skcT7hRYGUcDEiF92AnvY5NEtrD6PNFoBfEAp/UWWSJnNa8OFqVcST4HZ9YMWBr3gO4lb/gPCtMjDNbaZN1Z2pQZC1KEkmWZyX0BcyHU@HReouEtEitpfFFnU8hDKcE0diCZRJlBBZlN7iSqwFKhil9qcIIH3qAFTw2A3Ct8eAxzdJGvyZoMR71Ej6JcRUsfRwghEVirS0WayaV6lHzUNly7lGBQj0F5mRGsBRoEkMrhyAc1XOxMuc9U@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@1v0S@irbatq2xLF6bajmMyKSpxS2fjEQLWqVYBXHIAlewCsUJGzmFokTtSJmM5LxMb@vm09nWS9Oslm1NmOdVHLyqlD0E3HsosRHowjhYafCKGHJblgidkPhXNggbSjLafXOwSJtbug44brWGEriViRveM7uHqzamtiKFXcFDAVneTMmzAl7E9arsIOWuquTsb84AVlsoXFXEl3ZAP8DUYs2/rIuLhUiI/yHaQP4JdVOPAgWkz94G5MFuXrHHwAWXt9lkknzMi0dhIUKgXsKS7TzqNQ5Xvmb7DHhOXGsvpqsgd7tXJNFLZsWkNlhKUQw39MAFXH6qN1MKwh1gztuGn2KRRcswelwykY@fWu11s5PN1iFB5ewke5BwoxK@ab057acJFXEeKvsmzX21YhsprllmkI8sVeypcHZrBgFt8nHSK9vfVBjBKSlW8iUoTnPwsA1V5C28Itkcw26h9GO4Fd4lUsAzeAr1nlwJ3FaoMEPuYLlDxRxYhgXJRuA4xIN1NsuvkdHB0FPFey4RnWgQH4HrDZdS2FfmU1ZY8vDAFBV3zQAnt9E5lJ6JxB2NxCLiQeaTlastP9bAK3AWuTzpHDrHcjBQtbUFBVf@nopd9k73FiO25YSdIIKU1G9lB1pAOXoNFYoDlzFSVQTNKgpE2SYooZihfdQMMxQWdR3oIgxxjqszUhWbIZCCNhzE4mhc/hMVGvTQYOy31jVlwJyWojzR@sz@eEhNIySWaXGy1MKEWvvl3aeB0kaRAleknKtfY3siR5YOOtVEm5R6kBc3VBRErgb1tG4nWwpNNqG7TJpoIukkgfiS3foV6INQSdOWSFAZEEKhUBauoASjtbNhe5YdVAJX1o7Xea5cS8Q2CzGTJDUkFEBJokULXfE3X2qo2gt@m6A@bEAFCdt4lCpgphJFTRgA3l2EQAwybIEHjSP3ctZcAWh34dJK26ZmdE4lCyUkUNXHHP30aPgAv@p56kFsziVxPaiWNGKOyJCxcARu1uUrboTEFOLMjD6SuEU0HdOQgwNZmamlksRtwY44S2v72aF1itEhrS41u1ujVb0rGmakvvjYFJpa6DrlIBzNb1GYDZt9qjHgqo3ebUnseIDMZ5hRi70hkwgACNzB9PEH4cFS1R7fueLGWZTPCXLhzukFEcLeo4UCkbmuzlaoj2xMLaldInyWEHSpO@RBJmkjS/mOJymNXzIstldvHiM6COqq1h45et6UUlW2rUrJsznDHVU6DjwtDBUj@zCP5WiB@NyGf7LtFpeSA6TX82qmSJiaDQlQdCghC7fDKDIeOd7qiwspXPhQfTBTRC@F08YfJItFgqqKADBVG/0eWqo5OrrXrAZcYBvIuq@aWbVZyDECx2axMUisnO7l@pxcl/Cn0J9tlpsz8MHGWzFZkMDo30oUWCD@R41UbLPnCBOwpwU689AhUKUjOnLFzk8TUnleDD8QoofdmqmysEIU5vwEFjD3SlnCpmog8cRubdp148TulKwHYuNoAkRmX/2mZbOcdG1mAY5hYvbNFVoxfJTAJUcTmewb22Ev2IiUiqvg6OWykf0NQcgOU1SrQJScxwJKEsaT1QoJePVwS@JtHUt6IkN0pwWWHWNbI1nNkQxmfNvMGR7a3jECQEQ70yOSs5UoKyETyVstbPGIUCthNHimDfKQFzAYIeBroy63CbgvTTG0CKBsQI282Oq5KcPUGHcIGBkCrnkxx6gT9KhH8TClTqSzZqmdL@o0KV7YjU3cHImxW0hGLLof8hQxJnPX3BZetlNysInlbqzjQoLGXBvcYNFRUXFaMTPV7fcOTQEjBcR2zFQZ7RImXV@ysayaQurqhm2OmRIDoYeIM53l8ASUHVjhpsyirFPqcg5hkLBtFts8C8XXkZ4g/dVsMXb4ugwUSCetTPt/MVkBFQdQZo4ul4WTvYo2r2RKBHC1nIJsOqOpGgWkU0TqQ4o1Do9Qp@pPLmSJKPIyLQx02xES2vG4oj6C8wXLYQdSg3qJYxjI2ReBINv7ILdQfYyQ5FS8QPplq/0GctMdtbB7UgRnP9RT2a6e1QhLVFSs5HExhvOzIGnE/gKwPe@pgmOTm@ho5LrRQ9CjyMk@bcekhCzU5r5TKM35tBXtEF0wGg7Eh6Uj3x5t@nrynLRYrdMZICUQ3gEpbqbPHb3ZbB24U5cKhGS8HcSCyF/VncLftNfDx3SQ7aotentJJCay4VaD4NyVb7ITNErIobJJExyn2dGrJUqVXcQFIPPgPptJfUSlba5P9rdk0JLKIelNgnKP1j4Efw5TlaR48srliixs7TQRlCRXbO1IlV0dldZrJGMrs26b8HOGHq5QaeBBxOx@mqpaqI1yZFWsK@s1KSCsQSmtGbIQrWXTUNau1M/e5Sq2u4Bo531IGD1YQlVtMNmzfMdo7LyMC0fkT8MeSI5j4hDJAkWajm@wBHzVlk6V0s/DGQrIquJEufqF9q303zg3ApTvbH7yEXqmnidLswPirkGY7lRLjA/ZOlbxjfklKDR4NW1ANXvhptZaTa6OwFBxmakcpRhKB9BZy2f1cttcCoiqL9J4k4HFji6gq7soEFxhm6pBDxVQHCezmZXNFfwjx5ghEOYSqCUjf8LRh7yhxESYKpGjW3xVLcIt@uzHOhPANVS/WzpncW/PmnCvMSzhdISwRq2Wgt9VW5q2/jSTXQ0YJBiTdszCkcQCuGV0IcTZiVgxSGoBYxCR/5cCbonGpB4ehVx1tMvYtSvWaowMECYZhnY6j2dZYvUMMMlP7C7DQWf0sgj77jiXpwxj68RHZCRKQ8mWc2nm9xC1SZehTTsxJm8nxZGpUwreTkKBBRO/kmC1FENs1BhKc1aVVBSdfrVz2zA4fkoxPmjbJeqbGs1SwtwCwOd2Z2uqWgx1jELiiLGrYrvinCXyhnOdConTYQh1gBbzq44Q2H0mxZJGQzuy8AFiS6jwOd4g8AaxcVgKrIatRbEDNUiSGz04Upm1e7HawR8GcUwyFkzypdGDUc45GXDCEIjFGcWkBFDhLKyGmA61VdU0lRVFUZiLQ0bBBiPlm7NLbePzZxyGxGB1MMP3VfwIdqivnRmynyWu2nZoyY68GcpRzKnMebDpNm61Yta4jGjcKDxbmUL5YJySeuog@UVI39nRpnYVDzGX4UQHaEBic3yCkK66lHqJEs/YsoCYCIvmp8zTJNkjsanYpHJrNTqRGTMJIwYhSow4SrXh3I6nJrsf@LDxyllSC1tJ95gUWErsTWrsCFjmy6yRZwnRMqu72JaCLmxb8Y7IxnqJ5WYneMY8ZA7uuDDUhUWORPRU7PE5tkc9OgJpMZOlBxnGOSnbLypFQ25kPWxeBekqTwIBoyPcnUmqzi4c89KKCfNqY6HbOwD42wUZtmXwlxStDbxbmdFuqwqrAlNyXBWXaNYHDiOpFp2lBBWm@iEDghcxR7Yk1c54qUJapbE3cJ@ctpzkTApiyyLOBiSBbsfCMFnDhmq1OT9cvCNxtp4hVHJqFddtZDgESWLRCdl1C3bR5Q@iNREQgkdXqUsxWhNzTF0RPr7NkUFGzDFHz9S6HiYzguE6n5tsNkdyV5WrdjBvun4WaEyBZ5Hns5vlaL1TRQ4cYelqLzFLf@dQU7yy7Nj2PRTjs0ijNOL4J0GBnzgKpTiG21tKKG9YoaRIJlhogPCh2NnO4hJSp5PK9px9kHMhapVRdso7bSMrc04bX5IlioAqHW82luxuONAjfYa912setaRoZ9lkpEJw3InTM0f1SB/wixBZzH2AEDCklmeMZkUFmMo1gjBVyQlcstJySKIr1/DEMwdUJKfRgyILt3oU5GcENMfseyinK2Q9TrrZnL7G@5Iz8jI2IDOkGgsq55hYH8yMM4xx1JKjuYaXw1WvZipsC5qxh9MwlkzArulhXw8u0ZfvTiBYOsQsKIuOkdTOqRH5RNS4lEfKD9HJgbKQZHO@WoUOrYUgASOI7p81vvPkwKItNWctm1kfjCx6tj/wsEu5LkFIq8h2a@iQFMUCH0dqQZ0d7bLtvGMqXLVIHrJsmVtZOkLTZL8O1MornKAwnoLRkHC7TX0Hc5z@YLnVcen4jcV2mgsgJDL34S9HODdn0Z2ZtfNLFA95qgwyxWime73G7p332Y5hx0xkN3FCM/nWNUFQd8wU7iPa/f6CxF9VxCBMto0QHWip0XR2wIivZvJoTuNO3XamxGja8QBbRxTYc1jTxiBjjmGWVEJatyaotm2JFTiA0xbTftuOWX9DyNmFYcNipZgdHiFKiXzByafMyVpddXQUGaMRXmyb2et0zjeeNJy0dOQ/JmjhdQ4721q04ebEQRNMovHkr1LGVIWN5pxjw5Mk6WxiurbqFH7QN@iOlHYSltGry7LdKXafO4WA4e8jlB6M46rJQACVXw4OTOHT@Kw8qXYOjhXXIuRJOU311My9Dis7hTvVUXsVzn/ZmYm60bHj5VTPjq6v43IOw6RQkO1IFaXHGeFp08Bemsp56NS2C51rVC6q0b4i46kBRf/QPlXw6h6/pahqxsMZxBpMaZhsfFJgC5A/YwJrOlrkHIrKHWfjFBrJgVNcJdIQ@6VMMN1d2OzE@vByTCpGgB7OX/fbr48oVvwRQkjgyZF11X/yQ4x1m9LLbcwQQrkdUnL2srcQ0vzpRbsxbX@YxMP6iEEPSpdUI2/hwmJEg7CpMQFUsnu4tmp6ujq07j4me0IF2PZyWzDgWWKuN8fAeMx929eYZpPolAneSZIodDtZq7infzjiZ3qK2Qjncm1jQMFqNI6isZfsgNrYgweSQ@1RGaox1a1gr3ln/J5sjPh5zVksVRWT7MilAFnToFOACu1HzCk6VsE7QvyydJpOJEc@WyG5AWB@qQSYQpLAt1VY1tIHnYI2rO1C2omGXDlv0Z3OAigBa4dQLGnbVcf2ozsaBytJMWRKld@djVDkw7XV4@3tRw6QUq6Y2o8jIkjtA1lUCdsOkVtskpPil1PUFCCYP4VzK8LXNkZC67awNsXua6p52nRscttooivz4cH1mts3Q3EvTjVjDCHZHlNVq7Lm7YOdHTPxKI1CD9J0LCVoc3da1EZv@HJ2fmDGbzOcb1ALM5SlNxxxiA1OdpEv9kHszxKVqfCF29Qp049hPAtwyzne6s@E/NVfdzoGV6YkJxIVvOAuQryKNlHbg3wJY4Rh9o0xLRITS2CtPxkbqgkEYQ0FydOzFQ6zVmwD8FSea9SSzjX49nYrmlpMTTr/b7cUKOWe@GmNzTsVJGWKGN8O7pr9uePVl5rxo74VFDhdaYW1@1FJw0YY2coC5pZW/OlFrtH5bpG8rKNjUBgLkKuJeLLiMAZtk/fLdXcOOdvfQNjUpApZzZIj@vbbLFycw3J4TbS3KSJelvhRDs5rTzPqOMBSBqfGP82n8VufEnWxyRUMZ6ec7UUjCA5FivgN2xTBtwPFxgO7FppWdMY0qzq0v4iY8btNQUAOHLnf30LxjxVMpljjq@VdXT7n/DDlkEzz4P8D)

Answer (score 1):

## Sample answer: Python 3, pretest ≈ 3.612 · 10<sup>12946</sup>

This is just the sample program A given in the problem, along with a corresponding program B, to help those having trouble understanding the problem.

Program A simply concatenates the (32 + 10)-bit binary representations of all the input pairs.  Program B iterates through these (32 + 10)-bit chunks until it finds the chunk whose first 32 bits match the given \$a\$, and outputs the corresponding \$b\$ from its last 10 bits.

#### Program A

```python
x = 0
for i in range(1024):
  [a,b] = input().split()
  x = x * 4398046511104 + int(a) * 1024 + int(b)
print (x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PZvZjgXZUUXf8yvy0Q0InXlA4ksQD7bEYAnZLWMk8/VmrZ1lsLC7um5lnhPDjh074v76v3/@zz/@of/1r395//ktz7//8U/v79/f/@H902//8B//9pta2vjln573/Zff/sPv/pVP/P4Pv/7Pn3/zyz/@96//9Xv@l9/4d395/@4d/Z4y1qy1lvH@PZ/8829@@wu/8Bk/P//ul@fXP/EP72/@8stf/9pruXOUWva7235qL/XUscZ9z@5Pm2OP1c8o7zz8uFsf99693jEPP56zSj@7vvfy42ljl9V7eevazz2HP7xlvW3Mh4PxmXLGeWsbT138cV9l7XfN9vTRax9l1vXefZ7Fqcqou7x3Pu2O1VYp9b5rl6dxt9P2bf09tzyj8MrSy@S3fT979t0an3nPmvxyrtU4w3hnPw82qWus0t41eOfsc93BjV8u9fQ@B3bg0e@o9emrj1PrbBO73KeeUy8Pe@e8z2h7jI2l5ts6f8ll1up337eeZ67aytn7vFzv4ep1jHX65trl6VhwtsP1Xgzj1eYe94z99rY4URllaPL3PN1n8NQ@3r04be0VizWvPYZ/yf@tvdtbR334VR1944AXw@A2/nK2zr15PD@WceZs3gWj1N768gMvn@z1ruXd3jrx0pyl7VkPTqvFM1ysXW/D3zymYbzJjd6@NwarOOwMbLJyglYwDK9snO@U2g926S@xiMFw5i6ba9f@fL9Ypb4L4y1CD6N2PM8nW1ljY8nVCSkeM25btzYsS7zVMwkvvMlf9vJUzjrPKb2@eFzbntH5e@51sPzE8kSRLuNia9exFw7Oj@fOu2458z0JeiKjkTXE0OFihPg5nJgcwL04lz/RR3URQiQHHyfAJjGEK88lVrlnrRj61r5wZz/vLDxoldM6lynclN/yVsKY/3mJkWeM44ebv1xenCOVjVfaJBROaXeXur1qfw5OWNiUoGrYYfN0YmEZf@RdPTy2cGyM3R980jlkwQ866bZ25yFUuT9G6WvgjcZzDFxycnO@8@6OASvRiNsmMcWJ6iJX@D0fPgRn3QODE/jru2o7hZDCXoTYIL1vu9yAsL916KkzGlYkD3HjBmMwGQZdxtEmbCsQsfgR65PB/GfiKP6STD@Ly1XfOh9wjNfw9PtuHlTbaiQfEfueyu2KL@r@LX/ykPr3kNWH/Jnjmb3chqFILs7beQd5CML4IICtFTLCQN9kl8afZ4MiJO@zFxFKsK7NK3kn1p@XwBYCx@ZfnHPwmtjEy8nZdrD2eTgMMEW0vGAHfgExMH95CWljY5LCwCDZQ0AKAsQ@f9nNEFLp4tHbCd7x3E5U44u3C7OYR3C8ix/rQzLzEyAfb9dF3E9cvEHO@pCfdZrgXIukJKaXCW3akf6dFDwASitFGKg4nP8nt4jkZukAf0i1gimJPuBl6c/hETh75QXY/RCAeLtwfwAFZz378g78yYkII8PPUOWAd@ttcAPz8VHweeIgbLbaS/Tiv5bEA4LX3BhhkdAAGD6yRoDZZAQZAOZejIn1SNFbpmhz8RCJQ7h5l8FTMdfmrDx0EJgjVUkME7MOvgPXDVQsT2INS6JGAElqwgAQw/TkxuVaNfm6DrmFCQR9isWiHnAg/lJs5MSjHIsfMPOkIvHWnmjrJiFXAWDu1EmgFO7kRODLbYeYtxK2IBNQTDFJSHN6aiqVh/jaArlxQFLVTaZP3QBgFw7lGeIHQIRCQWRcXoOVMWcVB8grCiPRNzkDhgcFisneLLgc93q4IeThd//ytoqjNofgTM0fxhXzSAHMx2/B1W328mcAMv6c4hTwQZY3EofqQMiTfg2TjZ/cAbsLcdUAGPHQ0MQpxIIIPYYBCcK/JDTGbyTPMupBdasNxwE0eko5VZx0xooknifcmAz4B6pAQJCriV7gS6FWky2EsjBL4eREizRck7DnMeA1@ECwEpz4BY@ebWyYEnE/HiKQMakcRXSvJNMV8SiTqcg7XIg3Ul8v@PqCCBQNArTJGSgTBAAQAjhAfnAUnsFlBF6x5lpw9jbzPP46FnOMJpoS3MMaw2c9cgXVCikz1wArOL8XBx4pEJwNHMOtZNDEyIAcQCDIDBAeWgHupmL3jjOJrWlskZYELdBqxeaslFMOdj5UHpLGuXWs1IQ/PBwMQAImH4sYuVswFDRGzONQnGGJ0RSBWXgNnhmkFI/Vc5MffU7B9pRm46WK2HOBF1i8Gy8EKPxlDpwMAJialFBB0UL7bDnPCOeZgn8XOghfcJDXEi6ckaN8iEXVpjJzSNJeLsVrzXtyjmSg6AJhOM8n63jMgDdI3hBDogMatMIzempx1R3QHmkZXoDgQW@5PI/qYxZYdhXXOTNJzN0pvlSaB5aDlS48DGSAvvDvhpgqmSFxzcJBtWrmnFizu2mFWaCwUOrwVj4J@SA2SWW8Oh94k7EO8nCdRxI2ANWVom0IA3XXvywUB06yJZFck1fAKAlhYhPjy5@u7HyEVJAZxAqpSt1LKFGRiXCgh1QGN@kLCEmOIcngw@MK3BB@MpvA4p/upS7@f8ZhvkEUjpRPbQ8yvITIA7wTWtCD0DKYfpfBBxIgNiKf9f8VxkV76DL80p8a9BbrgpNLMsW9K3BWRJppvaJsFDCNWjssCOYmUYtTmhZbIA5gTMiaqsa2v6QbwJ/zNkrQlQU1uYoYS05zIv4UVgYmw8E56SNTGQeaRjALk1yTXxPqGIJ6BYGTyBb@kpwnyDbVbKd1IrtJoGEC8VGBYUn1T2BzkHZkJH4Ffk1boBk@BRLydLEO3OOoK9FAVlA8jiajk@DmsEQCeXhzzMuRwB7PACqJBZd6VD6CJz/BEnrYm3bicco8XjkPLqUB493JTIgELI1S0z/2B@8j/2nYSDbObztmKt@PAMChKCWbukQ@e/5NKbTfODI6nD8I8yZlno8G0vzUMDkbVRUmbjTbCxAoVxpKnRSDoJcEJTcj34mMZXMESgL8j3lVQ/2wE5WGQrQ8nkV9pTyIp9QfIo6T02ta6uh3lt0QsJhWBAa@O04kxjEBkS1wk64pKiAXnzaXSEWq6/DPlmFjySyQkiqxeOFZUCPYspWM1AGqrekrDaDG6PgghUtOwW8LiEIeXfHbHmbYfQGuxH/ChDJWJBFE2pLXf12dkMz7gFZSZxu3JDSx1dITwJRJZrCd5nakXwRNjsWqSAWWVcUGLLkNk8F6zdbNJ3XZANAAKBMmACnET8btAckL4lrssX@o0kTsTMhcIwjH97QT166YXxL0xB9AOZIAdNRYBKpMCEHR6GBsaXY6BtsZfM/xgRBdKe04cnfuuiULUAsYXUsDAZLzLzB2lXSQMLyq37SefJRnU0tguSEdBKJZgFMNmytJH3YBxy6RIC9y2RwKvG1mTDNwqFb0DgNb8NaBSbkPaMmRoYNqC1RXi1ULiwNPKNPySKkNRbrUZVhRbkloUof4JwRIXrvavoO2eMP@F79QEMDSbhMJ/B1BkGJULQti07TaYAfiT54tkCUiKFJUJ6r/SM2GowBulMBqY9@5O4ckYK/VfwXIfA0oxYeJDlBborks4XZaVSXC5FIj4tBExLH9sAxT@0fi2Ysfwjm8wd4Ahkr8SFfgJ11@DxOjSiu5VN8xrTRgDn961YEoieDneULiCG2QzF6gKrqQRpJkW3RimwMttRv5vrFyxQm7t0ujCujzVN8JRpMchC@ZiPtJL8rV/Uog76RYGM1GkmgP7EF803HQhWFramJC1FcCHPRIuJTHkl0WOdsB6DZPI1SOYoguhtcdCw6Hp@fYBqFNOdGMn6gQHbDGQiYUmUZAAG3pyEl/AVO/mCVAHyUuTeLWuBYjGMxJXyhdIxyt33RsNNFcR2z5JI4rD6PwEg1gNCUVa96wyvKxbSBiUhioiNQ/kJ1/Q1ngsZRen0TbWg0cMgv/kglpyiAv4CqXV1yiHGGP5c1BzGNluCpGXRyssQMfhooROWQQHEiKhj@I7f1hP22c3bzsaNA@WeNJNxqsSoABqfAe7GTUcUlSe5l9vgj0glgQkwaLLBFv7Y@jdRlHgd/xEycGbK17ALfyF5znxMQEs502VXeXAUXWohSRYnvWoi9gPoKKiDZaJKRNai2Nb@p8CmEEJYjGFWyTaCOwKLchlDwNULIs6UcVRvgwAuzgsRmAa48Hjxm2NsY1SYvx6JeISYyrYOnjACEskrOOHNZKKtWj56Gzxe/pQKGeAnOxItgKDImhnUMIR9cvdua8Zxu9eAlAomRHSIEVwNqiA9GwVsoB5U2BKRVBbJA4AnXLIy5Frh45rAmfEmhiZYmY0jKF0aVJTje2ud1rIvJPIJdS3jD5L1fluthETbWR0JQ1IDc4cpbReqFAJTFGWbHJ6VZJ0nT3T5ADIeEzqsl6pW4Rh/A1LOQeBN2WtUpMIZs6u9qkWWV8kHoD/rXdU@SAuIMxP3VDI@DX9GyS2HPUbmeYEwYWTFfw0epPZKrP2BPw1n5VI@g50neJ51RG6FOYFXamIwCx@k96Kc2WvKckbY8NNSdWzgbMbU7VsHgrdIdqK6ArX1uqaKeGDMCGH5eMT7/pUY/5u4X3hw09B@buS5ZI/a8kBziy70097XZd9N58WDGeok3WYnuytB2sL7eQkk/rxg6TrVJe0UD2pIa4UoGwj07k8LR1Kojqwar6PLZLYfvCFmnwtRGv4fRtpOBThClC0KljasHgJVj@qMkIsBT4HuN3mc/AgHBkAQn0gSOHQgFVwr9lTl2y8HC86hACXOCeV9FhpBVV9AVVlcmj3RZJOACLTbpVY0cZuulLVLZpdWtLKbAW6cT5Uc9jdwOd52I3lgflwILz@cVWn2TkE2TP@GQEyTPA0MuHOKSE0ct7aPH3WCH36yrSwAGaSv0uaXF5KoHIkeB/FiS5s5MOHsVzN4W0SnL4oF6QuFz7W2oKRUdVOjSaTINmqympRpGjRPPMCYrHjQ/pYtJfUIr8dFFxHdbzSdJdFbIWROTjDcTkSD1THV41jZXrLIHL5BSivf23jaJpALbRE5D75DRmwqU0GriD0J6WT4oRh4RM5kcIFd63/GvRpIzlqUd6m8EyGkpbq2b5ombAq8KM@zfQKLZWJVIRECgkOaWySeMU3JYOizYH0xzJzI3i4IPh5VAv2NVR5uS1gBegDoLmUIuySSDSY2KJFSHDtqb7YcKHO8zMENK0bRrbrrSuSpDayzmdaO2olUMW6u3bQ7w6X6JeZax2HWscm9ehWg4jsmhqcdsnM9GGVilWQRyywCc4heKEg5xGU6J2pExGcT6Wt/MT09XRy9Cstm1DmOdVOF5VyhkC4b2U2Eh0YRysNHlFDLktR4ROSPw7F4QNFRnt/QmwlM0rXQccr1pDC25V8ob37Klz1cbUVqSwJzwUkOXNtDwn8CKud2UHKXdXJed@ewdYHaHwqSa@jAf6AaY2e/5jX9xsRCL@R7SB/JPqlh4FCkifsw3Ig9O85oyBD3zR5pBJ8rE/HoWFSIH@CUuO8@jXcK58zfEZ8Fz4rLOYqYI8nV5RRD@ZFZM6YGlNMdzUAxcI@a3eTCsId4A5Xwd@ikU2Lcvs8chkPnFqtzetTg5blwQV30n2IOFmJXzTfnM7TxMq4g@VfYvm/UaxgxI3bDOoR7YqzlTw3dkhoEM@Tnnl@pcOI5ySZqV@guK2Bi/HUE3ewiuKwzHsFqUfw51El0gBz@Ap9HtyJXBbocIKecNyl4o5sAwLko3AccgH@2yO31PRwdBXxXsfEZ1sEB@B6wuXUthX5lNWOPLwYIqKu2aAkzvoXErPZOLNILGJeJD5YufqyI8z8AqCRS5POYfOcRwM1B1tQcGVv7dil7PTe8WIazvhJIgkpfTb2YEWUI7Zo0LhcBkjXUVoVlMgqg5BScUK7aNn2FFY1HWgizDEvb7JSFdshkAK2nAQm6P1xU86NOihyTh/Rte0AXvbivJE@zPn45GaViSWbXNy1MKEWufl06eB0maRAldKzjevcTxRU6VDp4ZoU8oMefFCTUHkG1Bv@3aqpdDkEHrKpMkmik4RiD/ZbX6JvkiVsh2JhMqAEAqFsnAFJRitkw3Hs9ygk7iydqJOv/JZMnbYiFkk6SGhAEoSIyN0xd/6qaFqL8RtgfpwARUkbKMrVcAsJYqaMACiuwmBGGQ5Ag@No/biaz4BaE/h0k7boWYmp5KFFglU9bFmnp6BD/CrnqcexOU8Ep8H1YpGrMkMGQsu8LIeX3EjElPEmZ05krhFNj3blIMD2ZmppVLEHcGu@NLefk9onWJ0pNWjZvczaFXvysCM0pcfh0LTiK7THtLR@pbGbDnsU40BVx30Xlti1wNkPsuK2pwNWUQAQOAOpk88CA@2qs743pM/3E35nCQX7txeECGcPdookJnnm2xFfeRiaknjE@GrhGBK3SEPMkkHWcp3PElp/JNhsb1681qZIKir2nvUzLxppbpsW5WSZ@PDmy6dAN42hoqRc1nHakYgPncQn1x75KPUAOn1/oYpEqbhQAIUXUrIwu0yi8xH3Nt9caOECx@qD1aKzFLwNvEgWWwSVFUEgKk76NdppddMdL9dDbjANZENXzWz7rAQNwLHVrG1KKx49wt9PDcl/CX6s8NyawYxOHgrJgsJzPxWosABiT96pOaYvSZNwJ4RdOahS6AqTyZyzcnPEFJ5XpYfSNHHac1WWTgRhfGfwALmfiVL2FQNJJ@4rUO7aZ44nZL1QGxcTYDI3G/edByWU66tLMAxTMy5uUIrhk8L3GqGyFTfXIe7YCNKKqFCoLfPRs43BCEnTOlWgSg5jw2UJIwnqxWS8OrhtsTXPpbyRIWYbgscJ8aORqqaIxXM/HaYs3TavVkBIKPd6RHJuUraSshE8U9tbImIqJUwGiLTAXnkBQxGCvja9OUOAe@nKUaLAMoW1MgP2z0PZZiedYfAyBJwrYs1q07Qo5nmYUudKGfDVrt@1GnTvHAbh7g1hXHaSCYXvQ91ihyTuWtuGy/HKTVs4ngb@7hI0JjrghscOh0V3srO1HTeuzQFjBQQu9mpMtslTIa@ZOPYNUXqmqZtzU6JiTAj4mx3OfSAsgMnvLRZtHVKXe4hLAq2w2KHZ1F8XekJ6e9Wi3UT6zJQIJ2ysp3/ZbMCKg6g7Jopl42Ts4qxv2JKBvBpOQXVdGeomgbSLSL1IcUal0foU40nD3JEFHmZFga6nQgJ7URcUx8h@MJyuIHUoH/iGAZy90UgqM4@qC10HyuSnIoXSH8ctf@A3PZGI3YviuDch36qOtWzG@GIioqdOi7G4D8bkkHuHwBbf28VHIfcZMeg1q0ZQY8mp/q0m00JWajDfbdQhvtpJ@MQQzADB/LD1pHfPmP7euqctFit0x0gJRDeASkels@b2Wy1D7xlSgUiGV8XsSDyX3en8Led9fBjeah23RG9syQKE9XwqkHgd@Wb6gaNEnJUNmmC6zQ3s1qyVNlFXAAyH/7OYdJc6bSt9cX5lgxaUrkkvUVQnhntQ/D3slRJijevPJ7IxtZJE0lJccXWrlQ51VFp/VYyrjLrdQi/d/RwhUoTDyLm9NNSNaI2ypFVsb6qN6SAsAaltGHKQrSOQ0NZu1I/d5erOO4Cot33oWDMsISu2mCx5/iu0Th5WR@OyJ@WM5AaN@FEqkCTphMbHIFYdaTTpfT7cYcCsqo40b55oXMr4zd@I0H5ncNPfoSeqefJ0pyAeGsQZrrVkvUhR8cqvtlfgkKDV9sB1HAWbmnt3eLqCgwdl5XKVYqldACdtX1WL3fMpYCo@iKNtxjY7BgChrqHAsEVtukajFABxXUyh1nVWsF/1awZAmEegV4y9ROOvuQNLRthqkSubvGrbhNu0@c81p0APkP3e6VzNvfOrEn3nmUJtyOENXq1En7XHWk6@tNMTjVgkGBMudmFo4gFuGV0EeKcRJwsktrAmETU/6OA2zKYNMLTyHVXu8xdp2KjZ2WANKkwtNd9PNsSu2eASX7idBkOujPLIu2n61x6GcY2yY9UJFpDyZZ7adb3iNqUy2jTbozJ2ylxVOpSwtspKLBg8lcSrJZiiq2epTR3VSlFmfSrnTuGIfBLyfqgY5f0Nz3DUtLcBsDnTndruloMfYxC4sraVXNc8e6WuuFep0LidhlCHWBkf9UVAqfPlFjKaLQjGx8gtkWFr3mDwBti47IUWA1bS7MDNSiSGyM4pczevdntEA@LPKYYCyb10@jBKPecTDhhCMTCR9mUACrchdUQ26W2rpqmsqIoCnNxyShsMCXfmt36WH/7mYChMNgd7MS@ih/JDvV1MkP1s8VV246W7MqbqZxmTmVOx5afdauTXeO2MrhReLYzhfLBOCX19EHyi0jf1dWm8TUP2ctwowM0oLC5PkFKd0NKvUSJZ11ZQDbCMvyUeVokZwqbik1pP6NGNzKzk7CyCNGy4ijVhnO7nlqcfhDD5iu@pBe2k57ZFDhK7ENq7ApY5ZdVI@8W0bKquziWgi5cR/GuyOa85PJwEryzD1nDHQ@G@rDIlYhZmjM@1/boR1eQFjPZelBh3JNy/KJStORG9sPWVZCu8yQQMBPh6U5Sd3fh2Z9WTJp3BwvT2QHAPz7IcCxDvJSMNohuZUanrSqsCkzFdVVCYtgfuIykWvS2FipM90MFBC@yR3Yk1e54qULapXE3cJ@adtzkLApixybOASSJ7sTCNDnLgWp3OL88vCtxjp4hVHJqFddrZrgESWExCLn1CLuY8gfRmgyI4DFV6kpWa7LHNBXh89uaCrKyx5yZqX09TGaF4bqfWxw2p7irynUnmD@6fhVoLIFvk@dzm@NqvVtFLhxh6e4ssUp/91JT/Krsus49FOOrSKM04vonSUGcuAqlOEbY20oob9ihlBQTLLRA@Ch2jrP4CKXTTWVnzj7IvRC1yrSd8k7HyMqc28GXZIkmoEvHh4Mlpxsu9EifYe/920dtJeMsh4x0CK474T1r1Ez5gF9EZLH2AULAkFqeOVoVFWAq3wrCViUncalKxyWJqVzDE98aqChuo4ciC7dGFORnBZqz@x7l9ETWw9PD4fS33lfckZexAZmRamyo3GPifDAzfJh11FYzXCPK4arfMBW2Bc24y20YWyZg1/Jwvwe3zOWnGwi2DtkF5dBZSZ14jcwno9anPNJ@iE4ulEWSrfUbFbq0FkECRpDpnz2@@@TAoiM1dy2HVR@MbEa2X/BwSnk@QUiryHZ7dEiaYoEPl9pQV1e7HDvfbIWrFslDjiNzO0tXaIbs14VaeYUbFOZTGA0FdzrUdzHH7Q@O212XzncsrttcACGZeR@/OYLf3EV3Z9bJL1m85KkyyJLVTO/6rd2773Ndw85O5LRwQjP5rWeCoN7sFN4n436/QeK3KrIIUx0jZAItNdruDpjx3Uqe4TThNB1nSoy2Ew@wdaXB3sueNouMNcsspUVatyfojm3JFTiA2xbbedvNrr8p5O7CcmBxSnaHV0QpkS@cfMuc7NVVR1eTMZrhzbGZs073fPOk5aalK//ZoIXXuezsaNGBmxsHQzDJ4MlvpaytCpvhnGvDmyLpbmL5ruoWfugbdEdKu0nLzOqqbHeL3e8tETD8foTSg3ncNRkIoPKL48AUflp/U55UOxduJbRIeUrOUD21cp/Hzk7hTnXUWYX7X05m0je6dnzc6rmZ@rou5zJMiYLsRKopPe6kp0MDZ2kq59GpHRe616hc1DO@ouKpAWV@6JwqvHrmuxRdzXi5g9jDlJbFxicFW4D8nQ2s7WqReygqd/jGLTSKA148LWWI@9ImWO4@bHZjfflxTCpGgB7uX8@fbx/RrPglhEjgxZV11X/qQ9a6LentZ80QQnldUnL3co4IaX71Yvwwbb@YxMPmyqIHrUvpqVuEsBgxIGxqTACV7B6urZpevgmtt89mT1SA6yx3hAHvlr3emoXx7H0719hWk0zKBO8iSRS63axV3DM@XPGzPGU3wr1cxxhQsJ7BUQZ7xQmogz14IDXUGZWpmq1uBXvNu/N9srXy9Zq32aoqJjmRKwFZy6BbgArtT/YUXavgHRG/bJ22G8mpZyeSGwDmL5UASyQJYluF5Rxj0C1o09oppJNoyJX7FtPtLIASsHYJxZZ2fH3sfKarcbCSkiVTuvzpboQiH6GtHu9sPzVASnmytR8XkaTOgWyqhG2XyG02qUn55hQ9BQjmV@G8ivB1zZFo3TbWltj7bTVvh45DbpshujIfEdy/vX0rFH9LUO2sIRTHY6pqXdZ8fbC7YxYepVHoQdmupYQ2T7dFHfQmlqv7AzvfzXC/QS3MVJbe4OKIDW52US/uQ@7vls5U@CJs@pbpZxnPBtx2jrf6NSG/9TfdjiGUacnJRAUvuIsQr6JN1s6QL2GMNKy@Mdsi2VgCa/3K2FJNIAl7FCS95ygcZq3YBuCpPPf0ku41@Pbx0zSNbE26/@@0FCjlb/LVGod3KkjKFFnfDnetft3xm0vtfKnvhAKXr6xwdn9U0nAQRrWygfkpK371ovZMvkeKl310FoWxALWajKcqLnPQMfn8QvfWyNl@B8KhJl3IGbYcmdtfq3BzD8vlNdHeoYh42fKlHILXmWb6OMBSBqfGv62n@a5PS19scQXDuSm@/WgEyaFIke@wbRH8ulBsPnBroelkMqZZ1aH9RsTO9zYFATlwar/fheK/TphMs8dXy/umfO75YcolmebB/wc)

#### Program B

```python
x, a = map(int, input().split())
while (x % 4398046511104) // 1024 != a:
  x //= 4398046511104
print(x % 1024)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZvJrm3HcUTn/IrrgQESEKRqsjoD/BgODIiARD3YNER9PbVWHE4sUu/de5raVdlERkYWv/3r17/@45f5@@@//enrp68fv/7@07fvf/7l1z99/fzLt//79fsf/vy/3/72M3//8N0///rz3/776/vfvv7zq@a7rfbqvbf64esvf/nqbdTXf/z49dN/fff19Ruv/Pj/P/Tdt/9h1XzZj/7w@@9z9zHrvV19ncY/47ax92611uErnZ9qjNqTBe6Ye/TRV/HbO2O19dp@r1hlnTHWnovfzzuNt9vr7dzTb7V2WPLMs@@e7bU3356D5@21ec4dvH7eHPes3u7ZvVc/PPOszWrrrMt39n3Fu6NWtXNe8eOa1cZ4s7V9@nErdTrPuY2F@BRna332O8ee@87H2fzsavO@x1ucfHO49tjE22N1dsS@sMVbi61sbHfu5GWsw@P44L61Zp@cnQ@wwYdJDkvduotVap5eHOfW0ZL9YrXBuXh93jkfq422xsNaFwN7ghrt8qjBShzqsMy82INt@ci3MVOVNuUrHAZzaIbLgyafWBvDDB6/7uXMbGr0WZfVL07gL07N91gZU62hcdZmV@dw1j5YVVfgttuaO7m337cai1xefNqu18aYd7L4Io54l@OzRyzOWdlcYUVcO9j0LI7M1969A9sNDTZvPX3d2Px7DXtNtsAzc15MOA8/Eh8csrHIYTWOibWewcefeLjuG8WmGvY5Z2qw8R4Bd9kj5@yjBmGzyg/vc3ojNomKfi8mLILEc@vn5it4i3h7GORNLElYmA9XV2AdQ44IaKNhA46DS9g3e8OtuzaW2uTDmryNfd7Zaw3DmqhbZxJqm8eebmxgN@zn76PY9sghWJynd2K/DQJ2VedMhMYrPH@N9KG1BmfAnyyOezYn5og3e9qHZFg6oZFdxAAxMWpOD8j2yDc2pLExACHGTrAsefOuKNCTR36RPe4@SY4y1XjIIzB4zaWMUhZt2AuHLnzDKtvEAwNYchKhdftqgIEOBik4/Ov75S@NyFH4DgbEnwN/EZOghaYnigY@xNTEnWfveIZoIPtxBcFMsM8yg4hi4o50NcZ0J5iEEUmmtQebn2QtJqrkPF8DZAg6cIfAwxV8uwz1Ry4RS12zxsZkHyHKsUk5nNcnR3Wr9QAmHTMJ@Jp8eesCIo78uiLRGaf8l6RcmnUYKfM0wAR4S3jzCFO93sdtgA74gEmBFrJ/823N/okhYqMRN2CJ8Iq/sB/ZDeLMRxJgZBbHOGTEArwIuo0ryHXcS64QpCAtj2L/eOfyI69h4GkSDcELIxTbfBgT1wryWPcJGWwaG7If8NtwJzm2SCgqN3OBVagHV0jhLA/ofxwLrC7Rgf/pWPKR1MWSYgipgp2oG4AASNZ56sSGa4weIKMQLPOVkNFewDnBxXZx28E2pR/cEpmNxw67YhWCgXJAAmPHcwtQJfPrYQlWYz/AENkvXvUiBkjjYBOxdzicQMCL4PID/vCw6EfMYWy@iclINiBuaDJL2MG0w0JDlSDSGlv10PgddxZxTp4SrM@wTXRgYbxD3BB8hxwmN3lIWXF24XH268efha1ZOTvhNi1r3YA0MZ9FghoAACfsQCieha9qpcIuI5QlhSH25ztLnKYaWWuAZatl6hkpiq@IITZOlIl7@mEIYkANmOAZKRcatTAMhvDkvkZsaklAYuJRAUAAwc0lilGfSb9bwgR7JrZBT9LUzLP0utA0PThdkZeCAG5jpyS9ETSIA4ITp7H3Pg6rb4s0CGb54@hgEQnG028euzDoZk9dSkK9ZPOE/dVFGIpIIMC3PgZQ5A8Xp5sy3ccNAc18Bu2o38A/j@Bf8Mz0SymkllGCSY@dWsm/Z1icwG3Ox5rEFzvjPFOrHdFyQlnIYMD54l5rXqPQARh8WqZzMEAzMiy0QIqlEjuThiANiEfwE8nUshReHEdi8YyeTBf9iHtxELgwxIg9kAOqQ05xQECf9JWllHThkHPAAeyFgMF3eNEdyl3msKawWzbI1nG45XpoohW0JA27gGDYyfaGROOa9xP7Ab/4EHtgNK3Op6BlOhFGyfbZ4tIompEUoUJgnZKacELMyWmIeVjV@GQfhVr3X9mQNVc0tEIl4AEkigUIRhhNzwICDrkQHIXD4j7hp0mELLoWC30jLSPdrR5QDDbFDvCn5dCtlqUId4hIkAHAqQwT4ORuDv54gWAU5giVQ6EFyjC1KEQGU@ZDGrCyWHFn0JvYBB5FFUICjsOySyPweLJjg64anCwHKo1O9tAJoK4xKTU4BH7pOeCOuJ66GsKJkSkkHB/riF5EN2F1fDYeljJwcuEXXCUmgWpJjLWK9@G00kt@rGMJezJqbCBNpLqwCtF0LDZhOEQMdlq8Db/2zHyMXFti4WJnELpm4ACWN/zwmd@UHJIZRJ5ikwVDHjNa7MVqZVYSgISRtYz/Y2hqJEFCbvAtP8MWNBNZsM3UsprLW9nGThqzxJWvXdGTUiSN4dFsFtgxW6QA8iSKd6WE2yNcn1pS@G7tMNaPdBBIb/JVEAvnia6Hik2KYrm3cgxJtp0DYXfldc9CssUXA8YugvpDEcU0fkSzY4Vt1Wcvy8IbOA9jBguIcRwzm13QDu8k9suugfzrM8yCbBQZeWsYv2Cma@IYQYjAlzdSeYb4CEpuufbF3iY4iEPphInzCyGJvykyWIp62ABWjIFlIZqWOtJI2HvyQ0Grp9@4li8IEnHF9uR@lL/3wlKAauOCP1INrH7CADyUuGWDSUeJadklPplgk2zg7JTSt9ITxSuPwJS2kfdW2GNtauITriUnwUyYGhYmOGgYhpVInk8W28MQKATAlalKJDHdsb7dz1nSDLnsseBbJXy2Cc0fcFJ/7/JPnk2Y0@aQdvwzDXjQjyQjayho4rXu2GEuwxqw43rbA9sXKGXZ1FIT4tkls6POiQkzfI@UZWH545MhEFEeANsRC/IcawNJnozB3oQsDJHqLL3hZVmgrRDutcvjQwKM7fC17fjDU@aSPa5tA8WHZLVHsmJa4PhuP1YGFsIzxyjatjNNHOZrAA6wSHqJ@KIe6AlB7KFQILTQooHYHF@C2HGo5y7NB05HEE0jWluSvgZD2UY9w@mZ8bjMKqoViCSxnjA906NjsC3XW34ZRCAorqAjDOlzY8HOnLeb3l72C8QEsGW3PPShDNeWFR8oJZQbYqcSB6rSTV3gK9RZLbMFBBbk08cmyLLjM4EoxQObLwoth7M/ITP0jx4xEFjsKnE84553uwLK0wPLDnFJfgTTYytGLRZdcZqsW9wADvnpSn5BmKs1Qb1rlECbJSYJ1bhjf5SFJU@f2swSwWoEjK2IZNEmRxw59hvUNzHpKYUQHl3Xj2zUJk/UbTLPKQUQRWRjpCIYVuJs0MY2knaZh1CB@QDkIYRp2aNuQ73ZHXBeTgukuCkQxTDn43IUWARhSGpjzKnHuqVBZBeoqbyginzehgILNpnMEbZIWvITp3V1G3lfWjpxGhABs1aAnnIsoGl6w1G2yZlIacKWcNEUU3KfskyIEXza0qzjKeTTDs3EOhRh08HeTQXoSl9xChEnpDfZrae3wSY4SaNmY6ggwde0D6Y7dtbHprYk8DcUEZjHwva5fhqoxqPGsdbvBrIsw/phc6FWcVPQ@F06RNJfRQkebzsnVzs9zKlCOeUSbr5Mkm3fPM17NmX/0MwQOT/hTiWEjhGLHwGp2cenO5bimHnD8vHsfCVRn6hIF8/ygrSMEwgl8x@HGWI1y/CX6pkN0rKDXQIV7YpNahebWVGuAvujidUxsOVrt4ZfeaQVnJjq@aDnMigUZPTlR9TgpHbfW65LkE0FF4UH1QfyT7gyLsU@bCVrNlABL/iPTzmSd5veFp4sjKgSSTjtEC3SfLinuuEKoZaGjIwDLWhH7YxeBBPVI9jmjQDUjFkwA7ML9PgS0KNMkbZP8j4tHAYE1buCwWSoiS5GNdWbKTmQrEUX7VYZnDy0gySfZZMAsjKMqXgGe6RDsemUc8IO4K1lVTe2ZmjnNHKppyXvuNKnFw2I87CjlvwCDwhkKMCUAJGf8DqpS1QDzhQmK08g2prdjuceSm@pBE0JUClRQYOSA1cgMeUUzW0I6R956dkAEssyRWxZ0QmNq6lu063/em@qGol8CmYAv8WPc125zpP7YZSKmAb9VQwEmqIVA2REaPBFS2/FIxsvPdntAfCU7S@ZexWtRWIbNjYTo9iuUYNs77ouWNKhMq6HbV9Ftnhqvt12gUAcdpsEmoKvIp3HMuxJB8L1jngXWnBmWjfi1U4gqAZYY20OaggSc11tTPEMfk4KkPTgAbE9lDGJWaARR6hcnqNKg1FVKVWqrpqVGWJqlF8EedI480bkIPVZkrYro1B7RtrhqYKrki5Gdj1FcIj00w4pkdEUZzmm1iKqycWh3E6D0UPnBSuyjJ7CFopgF16PcrTAZn9IAMXv5QMxM4TLrqOifDSBVC6lYK@MYifDuW4UC44I6NkBWJyG2mlwDjB9aaWmtqDeTOlvRG0xIstMVdAuxSDuhhCdKkOfTcYKchp2KYYRKoKqBd6vAFzDFtGOyrZJGrpbNMEjY@L3ZbHCKfYFT/7qt8x6JfelufkEFtTKTX1aVcWCnukEgaWaaTNpHMnXJM9DQQUMeuoaOnpKdogxNfKp7XmzoriBgDYuPaXwpqqT/jvqTOrqdvDgYY/KtnkC046anFGLowlCjvjGslYQOZjsF@frp6W4SeYX4SFlKmUqIGCrcLEjNQJoiRFiq2Da4RS6AWlxqWxG4CKXMp5o6rVHisDZwg4DLqUkjnmvUgvlsN1AvNKCjaQaaqtAnXzYMjXFew41nV6ABH/ggWKubdNUU6Br2h73I@ESErIXuNBJF23cGmY43DZ52b@XAh3m3c46pDw4k9dIWI6qCEY9swqJXxLeZuEg6j7Y32xOt@bVivYPblR1DwIqyAK8Q4Vrp7OHVV7TTfkHu/CRUFiiT95jRykEWCXACsBHjUHOHVNCasgXCtBVlbGSATScx@5HFSlBgfOvFHiqF7Uo@bo5/pjKfjbbw@MTrTfSXBRqj37UWxyKmD0gBJ8ksob9ZpOZm0KhO87l1GoNP86uOqBkoprfVallO5ZDc@pGbYZL8xMueh9ZBc8o6EfH71auE7UjiTcd6AyViAd5bMaYR5tGMbHInyQbESfHIe2VsLrifRMqtAUVwXbYqiwkO6kiSIWStSPkyWc0iFxFBTvheT7yCNYxtSRr2/GVkqyzRrHH2QFNkYxXokKjR1hRD4b8R1wGTpe@cdLFYZbaqFAjRXN2OVVSZeLWKRWs5u8WjmGgXrHoqJOSYJzZHskUHjLLJVvKtOPa9DZ7DScxT70Ky6pykVnKuinurHhDEEqhwgqlqr@VupVQmsPQGQlsCBZqbg78mlMCDSSlFWzSIYpwUsAh2X09CiaMYrvPxICamjLeVUaCXHL87uzE9LFqchAh3IaAL4QIK@RJcMzGxIGc2aLhxHVLfCAaw897qpc@HEp6rP4SZxt5m@8tr7fBVBYXFI6a7fr0qVZhO5xpaXXo4ZTJKalK6JVmKjqxqKm6oiQpdvK3y7EnJ2dgjgBikPj9a/UFdh1AyuVW2gobLqdzjviawpX1V/b@wnZZxemEg7eV8Spg7ARLLr8iOxDzAZPuzMKNWkfUmJ52MqWavH1U@jjHcERzyG5mZqKH9JzDXptM8EJd6zhX/nQBXf1TKTCzRAuvyiwxAsSryMnsbN1UaLfPkKo15QuBZljdKXxKeaYdqSin7LZfUgJl0Z45YcmvDfCM267aKbijsEz8H9sQB3kz28/hnZ0QNirWujCzZT3KhnJl4H26qy4GPbvqDzvSq85mLMPGUFpTp4zLAba4qrSbIdJQFHFWNxOEz3mJcwjtyKJECSi3/OZIuLN1Wgg1ypN7BvZfGR6wQF@hJ6oM7kK2s7wIIeRZ15zZppTZ4xFJN3g/0vgDXMoOx25uGqQOedR3r8ktPC@rMxsBHa7zafguSfQJoGfplmFhwJRcrEucgPrHxOaBkW6UmEEU@xYVO@WoqYSQqxYONFQ2QuyXCZuOs1usgDBjValEFdFBgLK2gXBaNEvta1vDhx1zOr9WOFVtJ2O2UenVBEfYWwAQXFRbpXsV9zT7WjtNxVSZWHp0BaISh5QDwHoQFMPfD@/NwPelGfTlqbjQQ5sw/kj3vvS@asc@yge4Uo1Gt3WHeBwE50iQjx/f0pDAM7llXtsqPimeipTqvT5ylnvSrione/Wj5@36jAlVMZyYlXyEFM3cVtR0RpuBI8Dm@LMUaskwI5jfBf4nAZVcOL7ZDnJUf7eDcyU3KaVjVE6@7MKV7LtDgBNi@jKVmCrGzhpFLvFzBGhh8TY5kgLLNTF7bAPZY1nNZS5ODajV6o@mMqsfFaRph6TGKd2rkWmlFNKMc7jmRREJtD2Z4xcFN7vC4Y0SJyjNzthMktHJLByvlldInv0P5e7IKVuURKdnS/6PB3NlYbmeFbMMhQoEkmLEOfvdco2RGyV7ZHRUyvHK9xk@pwn10Gw7E1f5o/r//sgtBKRhI544W@exSn0n94R063SEQlxaTyvTHEf5jqasNV5NkK4oL5/PVI18lIh4p8U7GE@iZt/cnTJL2JQP5SgvqTTtDaYtkxMfB37gItu5AYfP3ZFm@BuouYdgY@C1Ke8cZCbMaUj4XCKQbhzvtzi4HWkvj2q@TYHcnfPhIABHdLpBW@8cKTgMIcMAnNIop4IORowxiSHFazoXy@HHzWRRlcGbG5wTSqS63XqqYEml1QtsyoXNA97K1ewinI1bwUxxe3hnQ8pVkhDB0qkNdnScRuhYHETiLptRRKYcSNZzKWE46blOeVQm5IHbof@JkCyZjDocNvmUw510K0NRANTcol21lyGXSobhuAwK5/JqDBnEtnSejn9s5aSv3ks4JzLqVkuw/vgJP2zTfx1MiQZefbLC25x6C8q5g1eQho2FpWRZK31DvZzUkTBqly1tlk2pBLQUqymlYAM2Rel8pZWOz23ulJSaxnXAHaGRFOXR21k89Wd4AeY6UtDrcoxumApaO4JSroCp@1Uui/XozcYcoSPJda6tzCCr6HKo6J1HKLCbsrGBVU79AMh6JWBn@O5IUAnUXMXeyQvNGgnpqDx8Lv4E4qV7kuTLr86ZcY8itkARgHNCcbw/8D7tfIbKqisKS7LyFgnYQQLcMjOh5kzdUVp5mUk@90xE218jiMyxVKlmWtcdROkUpbTRMpi5IY4sEO35pI/ZJ1eqrkKrkCeVdkZh09ZmxneinJETxUsdzyHn065yKbFIPqGypvbkQN8ZuYXdEaJikeVrpDZaiWxD7CjVNSwF3XSaYade/Rkmd3oUb9QYZzYJamN4bPraB8qV/pqbbIpC93P5S4y273gZhjX9sK014Syk5FVwkG6bbZJY72kpxNgEy7wc@UZgcGaxnYl4ZeopQzpB0u1LEXAICE89xqHCVI4cmZMLsFJCEE5Bo1UGtcs8prRKPI49bVc/92KZdWV5QQInSjRVbqxM/Ol3HZefMF4@nF7JNV1i7MxCVaajBXrbA3TpUZYIGm8VOClpdtoVXust02Ho2UV5w6LC8uzwnI0S@MqVxrs3hYg4GYfCBADQvTaz0zSIWuqzypO@YVEmJI1iaatXhdTz1KyUQbxCujWJwsFHyXHz04sY27nTdiyyZAaqbk4brllHxFmCvGvrY1SeeraofuxoJMWwFGmdHpk5tLdWL/X25S0Hv90Vq@zLvUkqXbfDoGBl1KlkFh3hOkQlKJWinfvbwHevnbFnRzbN/sKE62pXz8Gl97C8CCNV@OhhSnCGMcZcI9feXuYTjg/359bKhwhg1SmnGWpb0asdJYofTuW8bCGvkv18lJfcPqDkgYPNobBpJ4h85iomhYN5Gks5r5dEpEruLlPWroossfMwzmBtEp3AO12DyWXQryI2og44mvbuqVqoonuzzm6xQ2nmZlYvkRDawskT1F02r3wYFdNbrl4GcrjmVQTJq9MYuJZTTY94Tyhx@DFgobjqth1BjVyfAdwkGce7PBIedQDpDXGzEsdeOvLGqpliuJt3beYC1vR26FZrwDQrUpadd/psYsl7jo6RvPCBSYYCnex5Ox6MxOAfsaZzS8k4G1TK@@PuyDCKvFMlJHuXwO5cNmiB7ivTfzZJ7HsD1LS0Una7HgFANVuK5hDlebsvRaHr6Kb05H0Yo6dy18Ra7/207mA0E/DIhwpq@tYGwQvJ81O7HaDOoD55XsvuwamJ0qbX4NR530fwqRZBJJdAdZ7386zqMq9r7@vlIm/FEGpeF5ledc9kOteZ3NCRw6hrTPl3ZUJKoXsqjVEWrJqRg9kqOUXgOGxzZYX2HRkuvYiTAk3pUtEVxTd4iJr2ytK7Z2ylAKuGNIPO1mBBz@s19k1N5Xl7l1iI5SnHjO9eXbA/K6vSzpWml1vWbQXvl2O/EgDCzLb6VLpex2mZxWiUlvShqbJ/ECjV1Vp0Km@2Hy@setvFG1zY3XWjiDk18@6OolfuCup8b6Xu6IOJSUWSnmvgZpaXEU/3QqYfonqWY1bv6l9vDuVuBNk8bTmk3JUrIY46Q@nVs24G00KCiAUSOvbwmoEdwPPabvROG2tHO9ajXunxCGWVhLRNR3LsaNB7alM5nVTrTsBUIJb3TXvmbN05aS6dqrcfy17EHmn@zcBpeufHWzzvY6QKWqZndb4BzSsn0OLN8VJgZLyh5nvsaLoV2OhSrlT5cesxuH2BprA0vtz/HbkNomYYGp9rqGq2XR7rRRtbU8f1n24A4G2Z1Kw0RZFe/a8eFFatLF6JjGoxpMoSE6e/SdXKJFqK5/SeGuL1abuj3GMR@1aYx5E7@h8IEI5pU5RQmpO99Dkq2i8zo@d9S7LK3tnrv9Mm6Ckw8a8QPL5mrtxzsPNv)

Comment: Didn't OP already provide one like that?

Comment: @user202729 OP provided exactly this program A and said “its program B is easily written”. I don’t know why people seem to be having so much trouble understanding this challenge, but in case an example with an explicit program B would help them, I’ve provided one in this community wiki.

Comment: @user202729 Also, the score on this sample answer is useful context for understanding the scores on the real answers—it might seem surprising at first glance that this answer is significantly far from optimal.

Comment: (this is secondary discussion, but) Personally, I think that (assume that the English don't have problems) people who cannot figure out what to do with the precise mathematical defintion (still, it looks pretty intuitive to me already), are unlikely to post competitive answers even if they do understand the task; on the other hand. Adding a "# Why this challenge is interesting" section takes effort, and the answers are probably not better too. The only problem is the downvotes, but I hope the OP don't mind that.