# Make true and false global!

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem

We all know `true` and `false`, but what do speakers around the globe say?

```
+----------------------+------------+------------+
| Language             | True       | False      |
+----------------------+------------+------------+
| Arabic               | sahih      | zaif       |
| Armenian             | irakan     | kelc       |
| Assamese             | asol       | misa       |
| Breton               | gwir       | gaou       |
| Bulgarian            | veren      | neveren    |
| Catalan              | veritable  | fals       |
| Cornish              | gwir       | gaw        |
| Czech                | pravdivy   | nepravdivy |
| Danish               | sand       | falsk      |
| Dutch                | waar       | onwaar     |
| English              | true       | false      |
| Esperanto            | vera       | malvera    |
| Finnish              | tosi       | epatosi    |
| French               | vrai       | faux       |
| Galician, Portuguese | verdadeiro | falso      |
| Georgian             | namdvili   | cru        |
| German               | wahr       | falsch     |
| Greek                | alithis    | psevdis    |
| Hebrew               | hiyuvi     | shikri     |
| Hindi, Urdu          | thik       | jhutha     |
| Hungarian            | igaz       | hamis      |
| Icelandic            | sannur     | rangur     |
| Indonesian, Malay    | benar      | salah      |
| Irish                | fior       | breagach   |
| Italian              | vero       | falso      |
| Japanese             | shin       | nise       |
| Korean               | cham       | geojit     |
| Latin                | verus      | falsus     |
| Latvian              | patiess    | nepareizs  |
| Mandarin Chinese     | zhen       | jia        |
| Maori                | pono       | pate       |
| Persian              | dorost     | galat      |
| Polish               | prawdziwy  | falszywy   |
| Romanian             | adevarat   | fals       |
| Russian              | vernyj     | falsivyj   |
| Sardinian            | beru       | falsu      |
| Scottish Gaelic      | fior       | breugach   |
| Spanish              | verdadero  | falso      |
| Swedish              | sann       | falskt     |
| Sylheti              | hasa       | misa       |
| Turkish              | dogru      | yanlis     |
| Volapuk              | veratik    | dobik      |
| Welsh                | gwir       | anwir      |
+----------------------+------------+------------+
```

<sup>All words ASCIIfied from Wiktionary: [true](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/true#Translations), [false](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/false#Translations). Preference given to first entry under 'A state in Boolean logic that indicates an affirmative or positive result'/'state in Boolean logic that indicates a negative result', then first entry under 'concurring with a given set of facts'/'untrue, not factual, wrong'. I apologise if your favourite language is not included or the word choice for your language is not optimal - go edit Wiktionary!</sup>

Write a program or function that takes one word from the table above as input and outputs a consistent truthy value if the word means 'true' and a consistent falsy value otherwise. Your code must produce the correct output for all 79 possible inputs. Shortest code (in bytes) in each language wins.

Sorted list of unique words meaning 'true':

```
adevarat,alithis,asol,benar,beru,cham,dogru,dorost,fior,gwir,hasa,hiyuvi,igaz,irakan,namdvili,patiess,pono,pravdivy,prawdziwy,sahih,sand,sann,sannur,shin,thik,tosi,true,vera,veratik,verdadeiro,verdadero,veren,veritable,vernyj,vero,verus,vrai,waar,wahr,zhen
```

Sorted list of unique words meaning 'false':

```
anwir,breagach,breugach,cru,dobik,epatosi,fals,falsch,false,falsivyj,falsk,falskt,falso,falsu,falsus,falszywy,faux,galat,gaou,gaw,geojit,hamis,jhutha,jia,kelc,malvera,misa,nepareizs,nepravdivy,neveren,nise,onwaar,pate,psevdis,rangur,salah,shikri,yanlis,zaif
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason the output format is so strict?

Comment: @UnrelatedString What do you mean? You're only required to output `truthy` or `falsy`.

Comment: Two specific strings is a lot more than the typical "your language's truthy or falsy"/"two consistent values"/"one consistent and one non-consistent value".

Comment: @UnrelatedString That's what I mean by `truthy` and `falsy`. You're not required to output the literal strings 'truthy' and 'falsy'. I'll clarify in the question.

Comment: Using Anders Kaseorg's method on a [related question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/174035/send-the-pairs-in-smallest-output) I can get a 61-byte lambda function in Python 3 that takes a bytes object and returns 0 or 1. Since the author might want to post it I'll only leave this comment and keep the program hidden. // The same approach (but with details modified a little) fits in 21 bytes in Jelly.

Comment: @user202729 Sounds like an interesting approach. I think you should post your Jelly answer, at least.

Comment: Notice that, for Portuguese, there's "verdadeiro" and "verdadeira". And when we say that something is "true", we say "verdadeiro", "verdadeira" or "verdade". For example: "what (s)he said was true" can be translated to "o que ele/a disse é verdade" or "o que ele/a disse é verdadeiro" (less common). An example with "verdadeira" could be: "ela é uma pessoa verdadeira à sua palavra" ("she's a person true to her word"). Another example is "essa observação é verdadeira" ("that observation is true"). Tl;dr: Portuguese maybe should be "verdadeiro", "verdadeira", "falso", "falsa" and "verdade".

Comment: The Swedish row is not correct, because different forms of the adjectives are used: "sann" is common singular while "falskt" is neuter singular. You should use the same form, either common ("sann", "falsk") or neuter ("sant, falskt"). Neuter is the best choice in this case, and the one used by Microsoft Excel, for instance.

Comment: A nice property that some languages might find useful: the products of the bytes don't overlap modulo 257, so you could make a lookup table of the 36 different falsey values using 1 byte per value.

Comment: The Czech row says "pravdivy/nepravdivy", but those are the adjective forms. A programmer desiring to code in Czech would more likely use "pravda/nepravda" instead.

Comment: Curious how you determined the ASCII transliterations. Some look unusual to me. But it's probably not worth changing the requirements, the problem just becomes "act as required on these exact inputs, accurate/meaningful or not".

Comment: @JohnDvorak "true" and "false" are also adjectives. The English noun forms are "truth" and "falsehood".

Comment: @aschepler The transliterations come straight out of Wiktionary - I just dropped accents. It's unfortunate that there may be errors in Wiktionary, as pointed out by other commenters, but making changes now would be quite unfair to those who have already answered. You are correct - the challenge is indeed intended to be 'act as required on these exact inputs'.

Answer (score 18):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>56</s> 48 bytes

thanks to [dingledooper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/88546/dingledooper) for -8 bytes!

```python
lambda s:0x420AF14A5F8266>>hash(s)%3317%890%57&1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVLLjtswDLzvV/iSJgGIIsm@C@wCe9mv6IWOZYu2TBmUbK/98ykldw/tZTgwSXlmpGGJ1vPlVr/9vjnsywqL8Ov09XA5fXyeHz4eP18uT0/v7xaDPYTj7v7@/Lx7eT3tHp9/nG9RxmhD8VbssTITCkZAR9FSAAzeQWkYRVFGuFrsofKN0sqLDxFq8gLNTAJ6OIKlZZwIqMEVSLBDBsa@msgRDBjJhACDZw@D4FTRtCQyVyvNCwS0ZBW5SsAZRoFgiUHVdBB9IFC1BiYjmCHqZ62VKifx33RjhhNSxNLlDV7aVHJvDDAJEsyo1ma0Aqs1vP8ZBnV@2MP@eHdXowtmy4WTwVIMNni1iYyZXHMOpWowai6pSzsZtJv3M6rPNpNuw5iLzzhuuG2ti@ZQ4/gFDTq9hwb9qDBDY3xLUTPu9VZaqxeG0BJCZ9wVenQ5EO0hsEoRQ2tI7DtkNlseTKrIc3atig0MwehEAEFuUtb6V5sS74RgQXbaWpHqf4MZhDgW6Nyh1tdU1F6KUBAX20M6/u2z1xle/pvZQj3e/gA)

All these answers do the same thing:

1. Convert the string into an unique integer.
2. Makes these integers smaller by repeated modulo operations.
   These operations are bruteforced to make the numbers as small as possible while not mixing up the two classes.
3. Index into a binary lookup table.

---

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>59</s> 58 bytes

```python
lambda s:0x48A2D06199310566F06>>int(s[:4],36)%542%400%78&1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVLLbtwwDLznK3zZ7hogCm924zyABAgQ9CfaHrhr2aItU4Yk27F/fkvJzaG9DAcmCc8MNSxBWz7d6tdfN4P9pcLMvxSf56f3@4@iPD4/n47FQ1n@KMq3N@Jw8D9fzr/hVOa7h/P97lwUu8enb8dbcGPQPnvN9lipCR0GQENBkwf01sBFMTpBN8JVYw@VbYRW1lkfoCbroJnJgUaPoGkZJwJqcAVy2CEDY19NZAgGDKS8h8GyhcHhVNG0RDJXK80LeNSkBbmKwAlGB14Tg6jpIFhPIGoVTMphgiCfpVainJz9ohtTHJECXkza4KWNJfVGD5NDghnF2ozawaoV77/7QZwf9rDP7@5qNF5tuXA0eHEKG7zqSMZErimHi2hQYi6qizsJpJv2E4rPNpFuw5CKTThuuG2ti@RQ4/gJDRq5Q4N2FJihUbalIBn3cpVWy8EQWkLolLlCjyYFIj0EFilO0eoj@wqZ1ZYHkyiynFyLYgWDVzLhwSE3MWv5q46Jd45gQTbSWpHqf4MZXHxNaMyhPvg8q63LfEacbQ8pz/8OsA0Z8vLf0JZqnt/@AA)

```python
lambda s:0x453CCA1066840810431C1>>int(s,36)%2387%1770%86&1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVLBjqMwDL3PV3DptkjWCpZuW400I436G3MxJRC3wUFJgIGf7zph57B7eX7CtnjvOcMStOXq2b59Pg32dYOZfy2@jr@r6/WjLE6ny7G4lMWxKq/l@ztxOHioTvnuV3U578rzudhdTj/KZ3Bj0D57y/bYqAkdBkBDQZMH9NZArRidoBvhprGHxnZCG@usD9CSddDN5ECjR9C0jBMBdbgCOXwgA2PfTGQIBgykvIfBsoXB4dTQtEQyNyvNC3jUpAW5icAJRgdeE4OoeUCwnkDUKpiUwwRBPkttRDk5@003pjgiBaxN2uDlHkvqjR4mhwQzirUZtYNVK97/9IM4P@xhn7@8tGi82nLhaLB2Cju86UjGRG4ph1o0KDEX1cWdBNJN@wnF5z2Rx4YhFZtw3HDbWhfJocXxCzo0cocO7SgwQ6fsnYJk3MtV7loOhnAnhIcyN@jRpECkh8AixSlafWTfIbPa8mASRZaTa1GsYPBKJjw45C5mLX/VMfGHI1iQjbRWpPbfYAYX3xIac2gPPs9a6zKfEWfbQ8rzvwNsQ4a8/De0pZrnzz8)

```python
lambda s:0x42744262AEA01A914800A12C>>int(s,36)%155687%95&1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVJdj6MwDHzfX8HLXotknUq37X5Iu1K1un9xL6YEYggOSgIs/PmeE24f7l7GI2yLmXGGJWjLT/f6/ffdYF9WmPm3w9fp@Hw6HS/H66/robi@FqeXw@FaHD8/PojD3sPTJX8szufLy/Pj6/lHcQ9uDNpn79kOKzWhwwBoKGjygN4aKBWjE3Qj3DT2UNlGaGWd9QFqsg6amRxo9AialnEioAZXIIcdMjD21USGYMBAynsYLFsYHE4VTUskc7XSvIBHTVqQqwicYHTgNTGImg6C9QSiVsGkHCYI8llqJcrJ2W@6McURKWBp0gYvbSypN3qYHBLMKNZm1A5WrXj30w/ifL@DXf7wUKPxasuFo8HSKWzwpiMZE7mlHErRoMRcVBd3Ekg37ScUn20i3YYhFZtw3HDbWhfJocbxCxo0cocG7SgwQ6NsS0Ey7uUqrZaDIbSE0Clzgx5NCkR6CCxSnKLVR/YdMqstDyZRZDm5FsUKBq9kwoNDbmLW8lcdE@8cwYJspLUi1f8GM7j4kNCYfb33eVZbl/mMONseUp7/HWAbMuTlv6Et1Ty//wE)

---

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>30</s> <s>29</s> 28 bytes

```
4öŽ3¹%Ƶ™%84%o•1±87÷Ðˆù³Í:•&Ā
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZJLTsMwEIavgiqVFRsEEhVXQSwmjRtP4tqVHwmJhNQFYofEGXoDhArqgk0DbJA4RC9SnLEdsfo@O@PH/I4ykCE7/m6Pl/3b18fFfjf93h4eNtPZ5VQd1pvz/cvsqn/vn38e@93@tX@69pOnn@vj/fFmAjmrQYOdnJ1MQKDlaEiNEgMzJkEH0W7gnMNyYK6KMJErrQwtX6Ci0qJBIgcDRGxdjYNhAR1RQwVyMAnLvEZBX1dgkRk6fqWkImqoc6zb6E3eYUMDAxx5EJlHykRHxxuONONbqojK0DFWOzawZhoSbSjxmvtAUKt/o3HAZBS0kIm0h2zLaKnOUQu1BjqugRBgA5zY8bAPyBhTphkUMOfRXfJ5yjcLl2M@n9jCAoRJDMWDsSQ@sDJ5NYpNppK4UcbdujbkuwB3R28JIvwbBSgX2BCYKtGGV16GX6bkznJKtERCxcR84BJEytqXEqVvRjPsTBz8e2bJxqglhp6UTCH6CGhmZZhfQKs1yCI@uL8rjy9faQqqBSlCWQe4mNz@AQ)

```
6öŽ9{%521%76%o•B&¦¿³ʒв F6•&Ā
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZJLTsMwEIavUlVqV2xAoogtCy6BWEwSN57EsSs/EhKE1DNwBBYcAAQ7hFRgwwJxBi5SnLEddfV9dsaP@R1lIEO2/3nZrz5ev97ObxenJ8eLs9VC/W0fLpa7x9377vn7/vdpdrnyM8vP7f5ufzWHgrWgwc6PZnMQaDkaUqPEyIxJ0EG0G5lzaEYWqgwThdLK0PI1KiotOyRyMEDE3rU4GpYwEDXUIEeT0BQtCvq6AYvM0PEbJRVRQ1tg20fvigE7GhjgyIPIIlImOjrecKQZ31JNVIaOsdqxkS3TkGhDidfCB4JaHYymAZNR0EIm0h6yr6KlOkcttBrouA5CgB1w4sDDPiBjTJlmUELOo7vkeco3C5djPp/YwhqESQzFo7EkPrAqeT2JTaaSuEmm3YY@5LsGd0NvCSL8GyUoF9gRmKrQhlduwi9TcWc5JVohoWYiH9mASFn7UqL0zWiGg4mDg2eWbIpaYuhJyRSij4BmNob5BbRagyzjg/u78vjytaagepAilA2A6/n1Pw)

Comment: How did you find the equation?

Comment: @PkmnQ bruteforcing, a lot of it. And I need to try a lot of different thing, like multiplying the integer by some constant, different ranges for the modulo, different numbers of modulo operations, ...

Comment: Can't you remove the [:4]? (and change the modulus values)

Comment: @user202729 this might be possible, but the modulo chain needs to be entirely recomputed. And the shortest modulo chain I found for `int(s,36)` is the initial 59-byte version.

Comment: I managed to get [48 bytes](https://tio.run/##XVLLjtswDLzvV/iSJgGIIsm@C@wCe9mv6IWOZYu2TBmUbK/98ykldw/tZTgwSXlmpGGJ1vPlVr/9vjnsywqL8Ov09XA5fXyeHz4eP18uT0/v7xaDPYTj7v7@/Lx7eT3tHp9/nG9RxmhD8VbssTITCkZAR9FSAAzeQWkYRVFGuFrsofKN0sqLDxFq8gLNTAJ6OIKlZZwIqMEVSLBDBsa@msgRDBjJhACDZw@D4FTRtCQyVyvNCwS0ZBW5SsAZRoFgiUHVdBB9IFC1BiYjmCHqZ62VKifx33RjhhNSxNLlDV7aVHJvDDAJEsyo1ma0Aqs1vP8ZBnV@2MP@eHdXowtmy4WTwVIMNni1iYyZXHMOpWowai6pSzsZtJv3M6rPNpNuw5iLzzhuuG2ti@ZQ4/gFDTq9hwb9qDBDY3xLUTPu9VZaqxeG0BJCZ9wVenQ5EO0hsEoRQ2tI7DtkNlseTKrIc3atig0MwehEAEFuUtb6V5sS74RgQXbaWpHqf4MZhDgW6Nyh1tdU1F6KUBAX20M6/u2z1xle/pvZQj3e/gA).

Comment: @dingledooper Your bruteforcer must be faster :). Is it written in Python or a different language?

Comment: @ovs I used C++ (which is many times faster). Actually, I was extremely lucky to encounter such a small modulo that worked; most of them were `%80` or greater.

Comment: @dingledooper I have now written a more specific bruteforcing program with Cython, which can at least reproduce in about 10 minutes. I also checked up to 20000 for the largest modulo operation and couldn't find anything better.

Comment: @ovs Feel free to update your current Python answer with the 48-byte one :).

Answer (score 15):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-n`, <s>54</s> <s>49</s> 47 bytes

```ruby
p !/^[fgmryz]a|[ncks][erw]|[bjm][hir]|ep|la|te/
```

[Try it online! - truthy](https://tio.run/##NY9bboQwDEX/7yraBVSzIEQlM8kQD@BEzktBrL00UPXn3CNblq41T@08w8fn43t4zZu2faRjkOcSx8FqHY9hem/j4FjHw4ZjpSPZx3mSsYWUEmjl5DiCol8xWSHt1Iynow3Gz12NVx8TXuwVc2WFo0hw3HJh8Ew7WGkhgdBmCq@MQIltjAhePIJSMVzaJdXsXBsiOXadYi7IjayIjgW9zYLkIyNptihW6Ubq456mN2f1//pnVi5yomm9L6S9r7h3OaIoMSr11yo5xe6s/PiQ2Es8v@QX)

[Try it online! - falsy](https://tio.run/##JY5BboQwDEX3PkV7gGoOhKhkGENMQoKcBBrE2Sc1YfP8pG/LX/JQat2@vl@/3TSvUs4er86PNvYdydFf3bCsfWdY@ou2y@GV6FUr@oMFBiGccTS35CajZHiHgS3QhilEhgldbND0HtTIe1ma2IepjdCYHz5XZzmKSv6DGR0mZciKA2YKCycwuHKExeRkEBZGsORGWNHtJAiaIXitIsRnvE1wf@tzVV0gD561UfAHooA2Jtgi6UYEQT9ngahfDUTDVhgKeqfRiTx9wpY4@Fh//D8)

Thanks to Dingus for a byte saved and Value Ink for inspiring another -2.

Comment: @Dingus `$_!~/^` reads more like Perl than Ruby to me :)

Comment: Currently the shortest regex. Nice!

Comment: You should list the language as "Ruby `-n`" or something like that. https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339 Also, I'm personally a fan of `p ! ~/...` even though the bytecount doesn't change.

Comment: @ValueInk, thanks for reminding, I wish TIO template would include flags automatically, as I keep forgetting them.

Comment: BTW, this juggling with output methods actually yielded another -2 bytes

Comment: This use of `!` seems to behave like a converse of `Regexp#~`, but as far as I can work out it's [not documented](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Regexp.html).

Comment: @Dingus [yes it is ;)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168549/77598)

Comment: @AsoneTuhid Turns out I've previously upvoted that answer of yours. Clearly wasn't paying enough attention :)

Answer (score 13):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>68</s> <s>67</s> <s>60</s> 58 bytes

```
^(n?a[^n]|be|ch|gw|p[or]|sa[hn]|h?[itvw]|zh)|as|ss|in|og?r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DchBCsIwEAXQfe4h1KUnyNJDhJR@dWwCZSozsQH5d499y2fSquI2LtN9GfOkEWnWzIfwWbh2ftJumY5Uzi0x1Xb0zF@5Ek53VuW@Rhuj2VfCG5tLwEsOGFqA9mp/)

Regex that matches all truthy values and none of the falsey ones.

[Verify all truthy inputs](https://tio.run/##NY9BboQwDEX3vkel6bInYNlDIEb9TFLiDuMgOyQC5e40UHXz/tO3LNnqEws@jrfb59dxv0mH/i5DHX19hDqVuvRRh2roQ2tD13PKZah7eK@walZZapw6PQ44n6FIhJlTYCNYnGn0Am3UlR4BL3JxauqiRkv0zVFpKqwUYKDA25qZeMJOrHhCSPBymWemBYm9GS1RIi2K7DhvpxS3c9nIEDg0ijshF1YlCyzUrnlSisaUdPWUveJCanVL1y5njf/6Z15OcsI4Xxuy/ZxxzVajrGAqaK8VBKU9ePkF)

[Verify all falsey inputs](https://tio.run/##JY5BjoMwDEX3vsdIneWcgOUcAlGNS93EQBNkJ1BQ7s6YsHl@ynfkL5Q44M/xdfv9O@630GB7D115UOl9cWuZ2yhdUWy9vfqm5bSsXdn9d0EtqoVDia6R48CwssBDCB32/pRcpZcMz/jgEWjGFJXhhZNWWHoOquRlG6qMF1MdsTJfvH7t27qZ5A84nDAZYzas4CgOnMDjmxUGn5NHGBhhpKmHN04LCYJlCMGqCPGupwkuTztuagsUILA1imFFFLDGBLOSbSgIBpcF1K56UM@jMGwYJot25Nc/)

Comment: Would it be shorter to match falsy inputs instead? (they seem to have a very common substring `fa`) (I'm not sure whether you can output inverted, probably not)

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate Yes it should. Porting [my regex](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205468/58563) to Retina would be 49 bytes + whatever is required to invert the result.

Comment: If so, [this](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/3zkhMb8mN7MmP6mmXKUmOj2vuCQ2tSY6KTk7tqgmOi2nKjaxJi46NSs7tzK2Ji86Nb08livO4P9/AA "Retina – Try It Online") works for 54 bytes (I won't be surprised if there's a shorter way to invert the regex, though) (assuming Arnauld is okay with their regex being stolen)

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate Sure. Now [51 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/3zkhMb8mN7MmP6mmXKUmOj2vuCQ2tSY6KTk7tqgmOi2nKjaxJi46NSs7t6gytiavnCvO4P//tMSc4lQA), btw.

Comment: @Arnauld Thanks, but I feel that updating my answer now would  make it too similar to the other answers that use regex (currently yours and the Ruby answer)

Answer (score 7):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>55</s> 52 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to @G. Sliepen*

```c
f(s){s=0x4240165C085F34>>a64l(s)%19537U%11702%56&1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVPBjpswEL3nK6xIqUi3lWBDso3S3Uul/kFPqz1MwMAkYCPbwEKUb0/tsZON2qqn8cwbv/GbB9nXMssulyLSy5N@jt/TxzRONusf8bf1z1X68gKbtLbYItmuV0@/FknyFD8u1ptPye58ySpQn9k@eU3jN/bMTnMNFVbzL2yOCo4g3Am0rF0sB1Qu9lxxEQ5oYF/ze7RV0OfYj@6sQeQuDgCEGdXxcBEolxopV4ChnkPOUUmXCWjyHmv0DBUxQI2mQu2OFY5dT6CtHOnJJUxhrOiofc@Fn1ygvL6duHWFJMHqb0K9I9YWDHJNx6nyMlsp6E4uldQmaBzyCQcSaR/cgwITaMR48JNV98dgJy1Mtw8kCaDBM5e@2y3GeDG0z/NuFhyKX1db79AEWLiGI68zFxv0JCVI4hD8ZlABtfbQ4JF7cxxIk6S4@uNKZFAD9dUjbjcSbCqge7@2kY4saLR5Rh9Nq7nl12HDR0XXDlVnKvB6Gw8qEKV3SEMNdHWvOJTgaW4DBPr3lFwe0Fwh75RVA4rjRMkBIbjn@y3rrX0ah/F@Gy7aHRxudGF899d4WpG5X/IIovYScrn3RoEITs1QGNYAimjJTjNWSMUiV0JrW7yz4TtLXXx4IJy1yqJFNF90zPIUkf0L8W253M3YedZ2RkfzuUv@xbPa/o8n/uA5X34D)

The strategy used is the same as in [@ovs's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205466/88546). We brute-force values corresponding to each string, making sure that no two `truthy` and `falsey` words share the same value. The answer is then extracted from a binary lookup table.

Here, the `a64l()` function converts a given string into a 32-bit signed integer.

Comment: "32-bit unsigned integer" should that be "signed"? (so you have to use a byte (`U`) to convert it to unsigned?

Comment: @user202729 I double-checked, and you are correct. Fixed now.

Comment: 52 bytes by converting it to a function: `f(s){s=0x4240165C085F34>>a64l(s)%19537U%11702%56&1;}`

Comment: @G.Sliepen That is interesting. Can you explain why the `s` parameter doesn't need to be declared with `char*`?

Comment: If you don't declare it, it becomes an `int`. Since you didn't `#include <stdlib.h>`, the compiler doesn't know that `a64l()` expects a string, so it just passes on the "integer" `s`. `a64l()` in turn interprets it as a pointer again. The trick with assigning the result to `s` causes the result to also become the return value due to the calling conventions. Of course these techniques should only ever used for Code Golf :)

Answer (score 7):

## x86-64 machine code, 27 bytes

Hexdump:

```
6b 01 35 c1 e8 06 6b c8 d3 d1 c1 48 ba 4e 88 00
02 c3 45 88 8b 48 d3 e2 1a c0 c3
```

A function which receives a pointer to the string in `rcx`, and returns the result in `al`.

−1 means `true`, and 0 means `false`.

Assembly source code, using `ml64` (MASM) syntax:

```
.CODE
my PROC
    imul eax, dword ptr[rcx], 53
    shr eax, 6
    imul ecx, eax, -45
    rol ecx, 1;
    mov rdx, 8b8845c30200884eh;
    shl rdx, cl;
    sbb al, al;
    ret;
my ENDP
end
```

Disassembly, while stopped on a breakpoint at the start of the function:

```
00007FF73978F4A0 6B 01 35             imul        eax,dword ptr [rcx],35h  
00007FF73978F4A3 C1 E8 06             shr         eax,6  
00007FF73978F4A6 6B C8 D3             imul        ecx,eax,0FFFFFFD3h  
00007FF73978F4A9 D1 C1                rol         ecx,1  
00007FF73978F4AB 48 BA 4E 88 00 02 C3 45 88 8B mov         rdx,8B8845C30200884Eh  
00007FF73978F4B5 48 D3 E2             shl         rdx,cl  
00007FF73978F4B8 1A C0                sbb         al,al  
00007FF73978F4BA C3                   ret
```

It uses hashing, like many other answers. The hash function uses the first 4 bytes of the string - by luck, all strings are at least 4 bytes long (including terminating zero byte). It does the following:

- Multiply by 53, ignoring overflow
- Shift right by 6 bits
- Multiply by -45, ignoring overflow
- Rotate left by 1 bit
- Access the 64-bit hash table, using 6 LSB of the result

Found by brute-force search. The search space was 8 + 5 + 8 + 5 = 26 bits. The "rotate left" bit count is 1 by luck, which reduces code size by 1 byte, compared to the general "rotate left" case.

Comment: Could your MASM code possibly be made to work with [JWasm](https://tio.run/##TY7PDoIwDIfvPEUfgBkUMCQcgasQjxoP@ydoNjEdCry8cw4ONmnS7/s1TakxUjM1k/tIjbZ2U9RlFegZmmNdBODqpl8KJJ1CEGOPAp4DnpFPlxDS2C@YDpd8/7fPHXtJktRr7Fe7zT3r/g0oHGcsy5KUx9Euitwku3y9qpacq1UwBlSFrhdGOeS/R6tD2QTyIaz98KuirbHk1H4B "Assembly (JWasm, x64, Linux) – Try It Online")? (I don't know how to initialise `rcx`.)

Comment: See [here](https://tio.run/##TU9Na8MwDD1Hv0L0nBZ3bUZYjm2va9l1jOEvlgw7HrK3tr8@U@wMJhDovSeenmSM1it3X39eZfTTxsgkwd9jomH8QKNwZQKFmFa1gGlzOB9PrOLl5XwA5Br8t0MrbzWaayCDX4leSd/eamx2eSH2VPTHf/uacSbX@ybTFBZ222Xsww@SYdyqtt03eicehODJ9t3i6oqu3UIohdLV3AWTTd0c9PR8vHBuHYyF95gkpSeonJXl2t@fUGnpHEOAaj5tFYuizCq7LvyceQvVMCbM1Yoe7GiwWE@/). Not sure about how it's best to format it. Also, in assembly language its length is too big; I prefer machine code.

Comment: I'm impressed that x86 is able to beat all of the golfing languages. Clearly our encodings are not good enough yet!

Comment: I suspect all the golfers just didn't try hard enough. user202729 suggests that there is a short answer in Jelly.

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 70 bytes

```
¬{~ṇ"pate
shik
dob
sal
ham"∧"nezabrcrpsangagenifa"ġ₂;?,"yeojrkm"∋∋~a₀}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZKxbtswEIZ3P4XBOcnQNUDyIEWHk0SJJ9GkQYpSJMNG4QJtiix9hU7t0KFLh3Ys@iLWi7jkkRQCCPh@Ukce778rDJRikrp5cz2MbHv7sGXj4@G0fPy5nD8sz99Ybxy/Y3fL83dWg7ReHy9/Ph8vv75c//44nC6/P7E99HxjBXabShcbC3IjYMfCYcVnKExp9hZUAw1XWAP793U5n@8fb9jEdWu6EPnivxMs5/fH6/Utg4oPYKBnN1sGEnuBlqTVMrDgCkwUxgWWIZ1npZu4UWmjLR2vUVNoMyJRgAUiTm7AoLCBmWigAxWUgl01oKS/vjTkltLvtdJEA0OFw5T0WM040sKCQBGFqhJVpqP03iTa8SV1RG0pTTA5cOAGMvsY4mXlDUGjX63WBVdJYA@FzHeoqU0qxzkqYTBA6UaIBo4giLOI94BKNhWGQ@MHI2mXdZn9LeLjuPcnlRCGIzMG07hk4Q1rs@5W0Wels3CrWG@bp@hvDe6JegkyzkYD2kWOBD9O2Mcu7@LItML1ghxtkdBxWQbuQGavfShR@WIMx9mmxas2K75arTDWpFU2MUw/0XJ/gE4bP@2p4f6tInW@M2TUBErGsBmwZu/@Aw)

Takes input through the output variable and outputs through success or failure.

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 41 bytes

```
¬∨⁼θgaw⊙⪪”&⌈→⊖Ｌ↓＆s⦃R⁹ＣV÷⊕O⸿↔Vf‴λ⌕9↶7”²№θι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcxBDoIwEEDRqzRdDUnduHVljFs18QRDM8BAaWFoJXj5sf79f35A8QmD6ks4ZnikDE@B@1owbLA6Y3vcbePMNR7wXgJnsC234oWWDvsyDiNPNEnAGWeOFPdUNsp04BetM@d63lKpcKW4@XdR7apNevqEHw) Link is to verbose version of code. Output is a Charcoal boolean, i.e. `-` for true, nothing for false. Explanation:

```
   θ                Input string
  ⁼                 Equals
    gaw             Literal string `gaw`
 ∨                  Boolean Or
         ”...”      Compressed string `bibrcrepfagujhjikekrlamaminenwouseteyaza`
        ⪪     ²     Split into substrings of length 2
       ⊙            Where any is nonzero
               №    Count of
                 ι  Current substring in
                θ   Input string
¬                   Boolean Not
                    Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>63 62</s>  60 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Neil*

A regular expression that matches all falsy words and none of the truthy ones.

```javascript
s=>!/ao|mi|ob|w$|[gnst]e|[bck]r|[flz]a|^[ejkmry]|nw/.test(s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVJNi9wwDL3Pr3ChkBmqZu8t2bLQXShdKLTb0zALSuLEyocdbCdpQv77VHa6h8Jcnh6WLT89qcEJXWFp8B@1KeW1yq4uu393h2braTP5Nr/fzrV2/iK3c160F7udq2694PZ6lk3b2@Wy6fku9dL5oztdX37@fhSZSLCUE1r0gB15RQ7QmQ5yqdEy2hEKhT2UpmZaGmuch4qMhXomCwodgqJlnAioxhXIYosaNPblRB3BgJ6kczAYbWCwOJU0LYHM5UrzAg4VKUZdBtARRgtOkQZW04I3jsDbUcIkLUbwfMyxZOVkzRvdmdQByWPexRd6aUKIudHBZJFgRm5tRmVhVVInqRu482MCyenz4fD08Pxr90WHBnMrscZCBTJGUkQfctYgubmgrsLOReBsCDIi99lE0u7oYzARxx33V@vCPlQ4/oEaO55DjWZkmKGWpiHPHvc8lUaNXiE0hNDKroAeu2gI5xA0S7GSVhfYm8la7n5oYkVGx65ZsYTBSb7hwKKug9f8qwqOt5ZgQd1xakWqkvTwnzOF0bwZMu1MfUxeeItI1yJu0SeRiA/iGHgaPl2OTmT3ouI1E1mWiTC@k/gikh/fk3D56eHb8@PX5HS6XTOO4F/NyG8WjU7frHr9Cw)

Comment: Try matching `rangur` using `^r` instead of `ng`?

Comment: @Neil Nice one :)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>41</s> 39 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
.•6ðó_ ï²£Ëý¾Sð7§Ê³®6´¡Žmã•2ôåàI…gawQ~≠
```

-2 bytes by using a shorter compressed string from [*@Neil*'s Charcoal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205470/52210), who apparently uses the exact same approach.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AVAAr/9vc2FiaWX//y7igKI2w7DDs18gw6/CssKjw4vDvcK@U8OwN8Knw4rCs8KuNsK0wqHFvW3Do@KAojLDtMOlw6BJ4oCmZ2F3UX7iiaD//2dhdw) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##RZG/jtQwEMZfZZX6REFxlPcMiBIhNNl440kce@U/CUmBrkICOp7g4AR0cOKuPYpYvMi@yDJjO7rGv2/kGc/4G@OgRnEe56tqd/rwZVddzednp@tvl/Eu3r/dxd/rn/U2fo6P699X8e7F@jN@Wu/XX5frw/r13@MQbyn3eXyI3@PNfLr@0cL08v3p48354vy6gkaMYMFXFxUo9BIdK2cUoRYabKINhL2EgdCYNoWNscZx3QENZ7UTMiQ4YOAcRiSBLSwMCz1oEhqGZkTFV0fwKBw3PBptGBbGBsc5y6lZcGLtQKJM1E2GLgjc0UnkmGbvGcbx294GQRiFhQKfrkk19Ge05inYtNCZ6KFWpVrPXRYlJ/C4owXuMUGyZwLJWGSqB519qK2AFvYyy1DkvlhXp2EEOZDHPYByBSmPhSgkQ7oi@42@CFMYNm6vLHOy7gDhHe8GVFpxCyYkTHwK06FPKxvS2jsZvGS7OuSzF2pPGEAVFymLoWlsK3BxWT/tTIvNRI1peqOLRfRPjo9OUC7XWdBtXh5NJvMSe8tOzKBVSlkAD9Wb/w).

**Explanation:**

```python
.•6ðó_ ï²£Ëý¾Sð7§Ê³®6´¡Žmã•
         # Push compressed string "bibrcrepfagujhjikekrlamaminenwouseteyaza"
  2ô     # Split it into parts of size 2
    å    # Check for each whether it's a substring of the (implicit) input-string
     à   # And check if any is truthy
I        # Push the input again
 …gawQ   # Check that it's equal to string "gaw"
~        # Check if either of the two is truthy by using a bitwise-OR
 ≠       # And invert the boolean (!= 1)
         # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress strings not part of the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `.•6ðó_ ï²£Ëý¾Sð7§Ê³®6´¡Žmã•` is `"bibrcrepfagujhjikekrlamaminenwouseteyaza"`.

Comment: What was your previous compressed string? The edit history is unenlightening...

Comment: @Neil Oh, I edited a few seconds too soon apparently before the grace period of 5 minutes was over.. -_-' It was "aobrcreleoepfahuiaifkrlamaminengninlnwobpste" (`.•bÙвfƒôSÐ4Ólα$šη€mªδP‚Á¥PnÀ•`)

Comment: So the uncompressed string was the same, but you just found a better way of compressing it? Or have I missed something?

Comment: @Neil Now it probably makes more sense.. Not sure how I ended up copying the wrong strings to my answer (the TIOs were correct..) It went from `.•bÙвfƒôSÐ4Ólα$šη€mªδP‚Á¥PnÀ•`/"aobrcreleoepfahuiaifkrlamaminengninlnwobpste" to `.•6ðó_ ï²£Ëý¾Sð7§Ê³®6´¡Žmã•`/"bibrcrepfagujhjikekrlamaminenwouseteyaza"

Comment: Ah, thanks, it's good to know that my list of falsy letter pairs is pretty short!

Answer (score 2):

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 109 bytes

-10 bytes thanks to Neil.

```
method(x,"bi br cr ep fa gu jh ji ke kr la ma mi ne nw ou se te ya za gaw"split select(i,x findSeq(i))size<1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVK7jtwwDOz3KwhXuwCbtIdcez@QlGlom7Zoy5Kjh732z28o7d4BaRLBGA5E0hqOJP4xwNs7/HosnIzvr3dsWoE2QBeAVxgIxgyTgUlgZpgDWIJFPwHH4HbwGSJDYjgITi2mvYmrlaS7lrt0FbzDIK7/wb@vcrtFOfn7t9vjZ8jJHOXkhnreKFBC0jYjESl6iy07CoohY2dowd6PSnsffEw4iA847hLQUCQ0cuRNUEY6UQLN5NDR0m9iBVdKwjHi6p3HNdDWy3YUsven7AdGMmIUXV/AVcgBoxGHqmbG5KNgCplx40AVkm5r7FW5BP9Jn4xdQUnU2trhjqmEmssRt0CCO@loO5mAp2HXQDXs2mBzu1w@yMaXL64M2AamkTpTSK6kqz60qoF1uKJu0J4Kmi2BK@qcUyXzE1MNvmJ@4rPrPNSHgfIdR7J6DyP5rLDjyH6SpB4veiuT0RsjnIRwZtvhQrYaojlCp1ICyxkL@zTZ8dMPJ6rIuzq1KmZcI2tFxEBuLF7rqaY4PgfBg5zV1Eky/G3M68UMXg3pjL7TC@garvcbrEFcsu6iVc37/1fz1fBy@5//fPwB)

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 119 bytes

Searches for prefixes of existing values.

```
method(x,"dob fa ga ham an br cr e pate ge j k ma mi ne ni on ps sal shik ra ya za"split select(i,x findSeq(i)==0)size)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVKxrtswDNzzFYSnBODQuUDW/kA7dmFs2qItU64k27F/PqWU9wp0aTUcD6YoH4@U8Orh6x1@vmbOLnTXJzZdeEBPMBA4moEUHhHaCAwLZYaBYYQJZoJZQBlUICgsCRJ5SE4miAQHwUlNWrxkSOy5zVfBJ/Si3Xf@dZXb/f7lluTk2@tHXLM7ioaGOt4oUkayOicJKQWPD1aKhnHF1gRhFwajXYghZewlRBx2iegoETo51k1QBjpRIk2kqDR3m3hBUy@cEi5BAy6Rtk62o5C9O2U/MJETZ6hdAa2wRrSWFE3NhDkkwRxXxo0jVcj22WJnyiWGT/pmrAUl08PXCj3GEmpuTbhFEtzJWtvJRTwdawPVsWuDze1y@UY@ffiipcFHZBqodYWslbTVh4dpYGuuqOutpoJlS@CK1udYyfTGXEOouL7xXXUe5kNP6xMH8jaHgcJqsOPAYZRsHs82ldHZxAhHIZzYtziTr4ZYjlBNSmQ5U2GfJiu//VAxRUFr12WZcElsNxJG0qF4bX91xfEpCh6k3lInSf@3MR8b0wczpHW2sRew01@fN1iiaPZ6sVvN/f@n@VPw4fY/33z9Bg)

Comment: `method(x,"bi br cr ep fa gu jh ji ke kr la ma mi ne nw ou se te ya za gaw"split select(i,x findSeq(i))size<1)` is 109 bytes, and also gives the correct truthiness.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>125</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>101</s></sup> 95 bytes

Saved a byte thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!

```c
#define f(s)!index(" %&(-.049;ADHJQRSYZis",*s**s*s[l=strlen(s)-1]*s[l-1]%3519%163%108%92+32)
l;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVPfj9MwDH6/vyIUFbX7AdsNENM4JCQeEG/AE9ztwWvT1luWTEm7Xnva3z4SJ9sNEDxAVclxbH/2ZzvZuMyy4/FpzguUnBWJSZ@gzPl9ErH4WTJ@Pnk5X7z/8PHT5y9fv31HE40GZmB/cytuTK0FlzZiPF26Cyvi2avpPJ6@nsXTyZt4fj2cXadXYnHcAsokZQ9XzH5ZBXpQ64ab2yW7YQ@RgQqraMQi1LAB6U5glHCybFE7ueeay3DAGlaCX1p3GvY57jt3NiBzJ1sAsrlEIRBIVwZJ14DhPoeco1ZOk7DN9yjQI1SEAALrylFnUYVdsyejvdlQySX0Ia1syH3Fpc9coDrVTtimQqJg@W/DfUOoO6iRGzr2lae5U5JicqWVqQPHNu@xJZK24D1oqAOM7NY@s25@Seyohey2QKIABjxy6b1dY2pPhvp5WDxOqQBh3JjclHrAwjltuMic3KIHKkERjuTnIbkwb2q95XJAzkjZlDzNiNIQJojTnLjtShhVAc39yY24ZIGn1TNanJ3hFt@ELm80ha2rpq7Ac956owZZ@ikZEEChK82hBA9zTiDR11Nytcb6ZPLTsmxAc@xJWSOECXp/i3p277u2u@yGk7YH6zNcSN/8lp5aVF82uQMpPIVcrfywQF5Ma6dR1kUSjX/6mFt@Nv7Ddyej1EcXSrPEAjC073GysOItM9hzVST0TtMXQaOlSBdsOMTTa77MHhs2fsfi/M5tgX/huByxgGLPaUh4@FvRtA3sf4r2a/tPVYeN92Wflce6D8cf)

Inputs a string and returns \$1\$ for words meaning 'true' and \$0\$ for words meaning 'false'.

**How?**

The first, second to last, and last characters of all the word strings form a unique triplet of characters across all words. Multiplying the ASCII values of first character squared and the other two together yields unique 32-bit integers across all words. These numbers modulus values found by a Python script yield a distinct set of integers for all 'false' words in the range \$(0,96)\$. These numbers can then be transformed back to printable ASCII characters by adding \$32\$ to them. Then it's simply a test if a string put through these calculations yields a character that can be found in a given string (also generated by the Python script).